# Run Python script on start-up (Arch Linux ARM on Raspberry Pi)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, archlinux

I have a Python script on my Raspberry Pi running on Arch Linux ARM. To start the script, I use this command:

```
sudo python2 screen/screen.py
```

and it works perfectly. Now, my question is, how I can run this script automatically on start-up?

Comment: Why not like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup ?

Comment: Because I can't run the python code as an app. At least I don't know how...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the folder /etc/systemd/system/ make a file named screen.service

The contents of that file might look like this (change for your use):

---

```
[Unit]

Description=Launches screen with my config

After=network.target

[Service]

Type=simple

ExecStart=command_you_want_to_run

RemainAfterExit=true

[Install]

WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

When you're finished run `systemctl enable screen.service`

The WantedBy line tells systemd where to make the symlink.

To learn more about the options for service unit files check out the docs: man systemd.service

Comment: @Cruncher: Try: `systemd --version`, this can confirm that you are using systemd.  This list shows which distros have adopted systemd:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd#Adoption