# Docker can't connect to docker daemon

Tags: linux, docker

After I update my Docker version to `0.8.0`, I get an error message while entering `sudo docker version`:

```
Client version: 0.8.0
Go version (client): go1.2
Git commit (client): cc3a8c8
2014/02/19 12:54:16 Can't connect to docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?
```

And I've followed the instructions and entered command `sudo docker -d`, and I got this:

```
[/var/lib/docker|2462000b] +job initserver()
[/var/lib/docker|2462000b.initserver()] Creating server
open /var/lib/docker/aufs/layers/cf2414da53f9bcfaa48bc3d58360d7f1cfd3784e4fe51fbef95197709dfc285d: no such file or directory[/var/lib/docker|2462000b] -job initserver() = ERR (1)
2014/02/19 12:55:57 initserver: open /var/lib/docker/aufs/layers/cf2414da53f9bcfaa48bc3d58360d7f1cfd3784e4fe51fbef95197709dfc285d: no such file or directory
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Did you use sudo when running docker -d?

Comment: I notice that in the error it says `no such file or directory[/var/lib/docker|2462000b]`. Does `/var/lib/docker` exist on your system? If not then I think you need to reinstall Docker.

Comment: I have the same problem (can't connect to a daemon that 'ps' shows is still running), except I don't get any 'file not found' messages when starting the daemon. /var/lib/docker does exist.

Comment: Are you using docker on a VPS?

Comment: Install docker desktop from here, it will solve it.
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/

Comment: Complete noob here, but what worked for me is to actually run docker(blue whale shows up), especially after a system boot, before typing away docker commands on the terminal :)

Answer (score 781):

### Linux

The [Post-installation steps for Linux](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/) documentation reveals the following steps:

1. Create the **docker** group.

   ```
   sudo groupadd docker
   ```
2. Add the user to the **docker** group.

   ```
   sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)
   ```
3. Log out and log back in to ensure docker runs with correct permissions.
4. Start docker.

   ```
   sudo service docker start
   ```

### Mac OS X

As [Dayel Ostraco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1978931/dayel-ostraco) says is necessary to add environments variables:

```
docker-machine start # Start virtual machine for docker
docker-machine env  # It's helps to get environment variables
eval "$(docker-machine env default)" # Set environment variables
```

The `docker-machine start` command outputs the comments to guide the process.

Comment: Yes. This was the problem for me. I added my user to the docker group and  now I can connect to the daemon. Thanks

Comment: FWIW, the link to the specific section is [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/ubuntulinux/#create-a-docker-group)

Comment: If, for some reason, you don't want to logout, you can use `newgrp` command to start a new shell in this new group. Like this: `newgrp docker`.

Comment: sudo chown $USER:$USER /path/to/docker/binary

Comment: I had no time to restart bash. So `alias docker='sudo docker'` did the trick. :p

Comment: Got this error "Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details."

Comment: @Guarav Sharma What did it show "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe"?? Maybe, if you copy response in pastebin.com tool we can help yoy better.

Comment: Awesome. This fixed my issue from https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/issues/100

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome, I had to restart the system for this to work. Just logging out and back in didn't work :/

Comment: For the NOOBS like me: "Log out and log back in" means to log out of your account, i.e. reboot your computer. It does not mean log out of the terminal (exit) and log back in (open the terminal). That will do nothing.

Comment: For Linux, if you want Docker to start on boot you con [configure `systemd`/`upstart`/`chkconfig` to start docker on boot](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#configure-docker-to-start-on-boot).  systemd: `sudo systemctl enable docker`, chkconfig: `sudo chkconfig docker on`, upstart is on by default.

Answer (score 212):

### Linux

To run docker daemon on Linux (from [CLI](https://docs.docker.com/v1.6/reference/commandline/cli/)), run:

```
$ sudo service docker start # Ubuntu/Debian
```

<sup>Note: Skip the `$` character when copy and pasting.</sup>

On RedHat/CentOS, run: `sudo systemctl start docker`.

To initialize the "base" filesystem, run:

```
$ sudo service docker stop
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
$ sudo service docker start
```

or manually like:

```
$ sudo docker -d --storage-opt dm.basesize=20G
```

#### Install `docker-machine` on Linux

To install machine binaries on Linux:

- locally:

  ```
  install -vm755 <(curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.5.3/docker-machine_linux-amd64) $HOME/bin/docker-machine
  ```
- global:

  ```
  sudo bash -c 'install -vm755 <(curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.5.3/docker-machine_linux-amd64) /usr/local/bin/docker-machine'
  ```

#### macOS

On macOS the `docker` binary is only a client and you cannot use it to run the docker daemon, because Docker daemon uses Linux-specific kernel features, therefore you can’t run Docker natively in OS X. So you have to install `docker-machine` in order to create VM and attach to it.

#### Install `docker-machine` on macOS

If you don't have [`docker-machine`](https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/) command yet, install it by using one of the following methods:

- Using [Brew](https://brew.sh/) command: `brew install docker-machine docker`.
- manually from [GitHub](https://github.com/docker/machine):

  ```
  install -v <(curl https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.5.3/docker-machine_linux-amd64) /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
  ```

See: [Get started with Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/).

#### Configure `docker-machine` on macOS

To start *Docker Machine* via Homebrew, run:

```
brew services start docker-machine
```

To create a `default` machine (if you don't have one, see: `docker-machine ls`):

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
```

Then set-up the environment for the Docker client:

```
eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

Then double-check by listing containers:

```
docker ps
```

See: [Get started with Docker Machine and a local VM](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/).

---

#### Install *Docker.app* on macOS

Alternatively to above solution, you can install a Docker app by:

```
brew cask install docker
```

Check this [post for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49719997/55075). See also: [Cannot connect to the Docker daemon on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44084846/55075)

Comment: sudo service docker start works with Docker 1.9.1 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: thanks. this is what worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04. everything else failed.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me on Mac OSX with hardware older than 2010. I had to install `docker-toolbox` from https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_mac/

Comment: I needed to install docker-compose, docker-machine and docker via Homebrew then it worked fine!

Comment: I had this problem on CentOS 7.6 with docker 18 and `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker` and then restarting did the trick. I was really stuck and no other solution worked for me.

Answer (score 143):

If you are running Docker on OS X, running the following eval has worked for me.

```
eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

If you'd prefer not to have to run this eval statement on every terminal session, you can add this to your `bash_profile`:

```
#Docker
eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

Be sure to restart the terminal session or run source on `bash_profile` for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Same here, if I try this alone I often get `Error checking TLS connection: Host is not running`... running this eval after the command `docker-machine start default` did the trick.

Answer (score 101):

After a detailed investigation, this issue seems to happen **every time after Mac OS X is rebooted** (or the Docker virtual machine is restarted) which prevents the Docker client from connecting to the Docker daemon.

To solve the issue, you can either:

A) Reinstall Docker Toolbox using the official installer (https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox), or simply

B) Run the following commands in order:

```
# First make sure that the virtual machine is running
docker-machine start default

# Regenerate TLS connection certs, requires confirmation
docker-machine regenerate-certs default

# Finally, set env
eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

C) Same as (B), you can also copy and paste the following line to run all of the three commands:

```
docker-machine start default; docker-machine regenerate-certs default; eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

In case you get the following error:

```
Error getting SSH command: Something went wrong running an SSH command!
command : cat /etc/os-release
err     : exit status 255
output  :
```

just re-run the three commands another time, and it should work the second time.

Comment: I'm getting Host does not exist: "default"

Comment: @RomanGaufman: does this work for you: docker-machine start default?

Comment: @RomanGaufman I had to restart my terminal before the command executed successfully.

Comment: is this because the virtual box vm's ip changes every time you reboot your mac?

Comment: @RomanGaufman's error is solved by the answer (currently) below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34887761/634576

Comment: If you installed using the official Docker Toolbox, the "Docker Quickstart Terminal" opens a new Terminal with valid credentials.

Comment: @Jason installing Docker Toolbox solves the issue but you have to re-install it every time after Mac OS X is rebooted.

Answer (score 53):

This usually happens when you are not in the `docker` group. You can add yourself to the `docker` group with:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker yourusername
```

or

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)
```

After this, you need to logout and log back into the server.

Alternatively, you can `sudo` every Docker command.

Comment: and if group doesn't exist: sudo groupadd docker

Answer (score 42):

If all the other solutions above don't work you can try checking the ownership of `/var/run/docker.sock`:

```
ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
```

If you're not the owner then change ownership with the command:

```
sudo chown *your-username* /var/run/docker.sock
```

Then you can go ahead and try executing the Docker commands hassle-free :D

Comment: I have started with this answer, and this helped me!

Comment: Problem with this approach is that, you have to repeat this step every time the daemon is restarted

Comment: Hi @MFIhsan a smart sys-admin would tell you to simply create a bash script of those commands and & add it to crontab to have it run at reboot/startup as explained here > https://stackoverflow.com/a/29247942/3469960

Comment: A common user should never own a sock! If you don't own the sock then make sure you're in the wheel group and the group the sock belongs to...not the sock owners group!

Comment: Does this `sudo chown $(whoami) /var/run/docker.sock` also works?

Comment: @kevthanewversi I disagree that a smart sysadmin would do that crontab black magic... it's a bad thing to do, because you're hijacking ownership of the file. Perhaps things were different when you wrote this answer, but the appropriate thing to do is have the user trying to access the file in the group that the file belongs to. Ownership of this file should be as specified:
`srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 May  7 13:07 /var/run/docker.sock`. Adding the user with problems to the docker group is all that is needed to be done...

Answer (score 29):

You can use the command

```
sudo service docker stop && sudo service docker start
```

OR

```
sudo service docker restart
```

to simply restart it.

Comment: with `systemd`: `sudo systemctl restart docker`

Answer (score 19):

The best way to find out why Docker isn't working will be to run the daemon manually.

```
$ sudo service docker stop
$ ps aux | grep docker  # do this until you don't see /usr/bin/docker -d
$ /usr/bin/docker -d
```

The Docker daemon logs to STDOUT, so it will start spitting out whatever it's doing.

Here was what my problem was:

```
[8bf47e42.initserver()] Creating pidfile
2015/01/11 15:20:33 pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid
```

This was because the instance had been cloned from another virtual machine. I just had to remove the pidfile, and everything worked afterwards.

Of course, instead of blindly assuming this will work, I'd suggest running the daemon manually one more time and reviewing the log output for any other errors before starting the service back up.

Comment: That's also what helped me to find the issue (I unfortunately saw your answer after though). Mine was the missing `apparmor` package.

Comment: This solution worked for me. After I deleted /var/run/docker.pid, I was finally able to start the docker.

Comment: Warning: '-d' is deprecated, it will be removed soon. See usage.
WARN[0000] please use 'docker daemon' instead.

Comment: flag provided but not defined: -d

Comment: To run the docker daemon manually in latest versions with debug enabled use: `dockerd -D`

Answer (score 18):

Do a `ps aux | grep docker` to see if the daemon is running. If not run `/etc/init.d/docker start`

Comment: I have the same problem. 'ps' shows that my docker process is still running.

Comment: stopping and starting docker(which was already running) straightened me out.

Comment: `sudo service docker start` tells me "docker start/running, process 4633" then `sudo service docker status` tells "docker stop/waiting"

Answer (score 17):

### Use [Docker CE app](https://www.docker.com/community-edition#/download)

#### macOS

Use the new *[Docker Community Edition app](https://www.docker.com/community-edition)* for macOS. For example:

1. Uninstall all Docker Homebrew packages which you've installed so far:

   ```
    brew uninstall docker-compose
    brew uninstall docker-machine
    brew uninstall docker
   ```
2. Install an app [manually](https://www.docker.com/community-edition#/download) or via [Homebrew-Cask](https://caskroom.github.io/):

   ```
    brew install --cask docker
   ```

<sup>Note: This app will create necessary links to `docker`, `docker-compose`, `docker-machine`, etc.</sup>

1. After running the app, checkout the a Docker whale icon in the status menu.
2. Now you should be able to use `docker`, `docker-compose`, `docker-machine` commands as usual in the *Terminal*.

Related:

- [Brew install docker does not include docker engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40523307/55075)
- [Cannot connect to the Docker daemon on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44084846/55075)

#### Linux/Windows

Download the [Docker CE from the download page](https://www.docker.com/community-edition#/download) and follow the instructions.

Comment: 2018-5-20 note: the Docker CE app on macOS is pretty crappy. everytime I open it it just freeze right the way, can't do anything. I tried to Google and fix the problem, so far still working on it

Comment: This is the correct answer for the reported issue, thanks!

Comment: Thanks. The syntax is slightly different on latest brew/Big Sur:
brew install --cask docker

Comment: `brew install --cask docker` (as of 2021)

Comment: THis did not fix the error for me on macOS.

Answer (score 16):

If you get the message `Can't connect to docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?`, you can check it by `docker version`.

If you see the information like [Docker Client is running. but Docker Server is not](http://7xqaje.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/%E5%B1%8F%E5%B9%95%E5%BF%AB%E7%85%A7%202016-06-13%20%E4%B8%8A%E5%8D%8810.04.20.png), it's obviously you need to start the Docker server.

In CentOS, you can use `service` to start or stop the Docker server.

```
$ sudo service docker stop
$ sudo service docker start
```

Then, after you type `docker version`, you will get the information of [Docker Client and Docker Server](http://7xqaje.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/%E5%B1%8F%E5%B9%95%E5%BF%AB%E7%85%A7%202016-06-13%20%E4%B8%8A%E5%8D%8810.04.37.png), and the Docker daemon has been started.

Comment: `sudo service docker start` also worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Cent os 7, have to do it each time i start docker.

Comment: @Paddy You need to enable the service after stating it, and it will run if the system is started and stay running in the background.

Comment: All these answers that say: "You need to sudo systemctl start docker" always assume there is a docker service to start. If there were any issues installing docker, a service configuration file may not even exist, in which case you'de get: "Unit docker.service not loaded"

Answer (score 12):

I have similar problem. I had to logout and login again to shell because I have just installed Docker and following command didn't show in my environment.

```
export DOCKER_HOST=127.0.0.1:4243 >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: I just needed to logout and log back in. All fixed!

Comment: This solved my problem! I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 as WSL.
The only thing that I had to change was the default port number:

export DOCKER_HOST=127.0.0.1:2375 >> ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 12):

I restart Docker after installing it:

```
$ sudo service docker stop
$ sudo service docker start
```

And it works.

Answer (score 11):

You might be on a different docker context if you're on linux and have Docker Desktop installed. Try running the following command:

```
docker context use default
```

And try again whatever you where trying to do before. You might need to start the docker service with

```
service docker start
```

In case you want to check all contexts in your machine:

```
docker context list
```

And you'll see which ones you can switch to. More detailed info from [here](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/linuxfaqs/#how-do-i-switch-between-docker-desktop-and-docker-engine):

> When installing Docker Desktop, a dedicated "desktop-linux" context is created to interact with Docker Desktop. On startup, Docker Desktop automatically sets its own context (desktop-linux) as the current context. This means that subsequent Docker CLI commands target Docker Desktop. On shutdown, Docker Desktop resets the current context to the default context.

Answer (score 9):

I have faced this problem, and I restarted Docker using these commands:

```
$ sudo service docker stop
$ sudo service docker start
```

But I did not solve my problem, because I forgot to execute my Docker commands without `sudo`. For those who faces this problem, try to check that.

Try

```
$ sudo docker info
```

instead of this:

```
$ docker info
```

Comment: This was *exactly* my problem when trying to run `docker build` on Ubuntu Xenial.

Answer (score 9):

At April 2020 on MacOS Catalina, you just need to open the desktop application:

[image: docker app running]

Comment: Plus,  open docker->preference -> kubernetes -> tick on "enable kubernetes"

Answer (score 8):

I have the same error and trying `docker-machine regenerate-certs` or `eval..` did not work for me.

This on OS X 10.11.3 (El Capitan) and Docker v1.10.1. I was able to fix it only by deleting and recreating docker-machine again. [Source](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/2879#issuecomment-173214714)

If running `docker-machine ls`, it shows you a similar output to the one below;

> DOCKER
>
> Unknown
>
> ERRORS
>
> Unable to query docker version: Cannot
>   connect to the docker engine endpoint

Try removing your Docker machine with;

```
docker-machine rm -f default
```

Where `default` is your Docker machine name. Then;

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox default
```

Creates a new Docker machine.

Double check that everything looks normal now (no errors or unknown Docker) with:

```
docker-machine ls
```

Finally don't forget to run `"$(docker-machine env default)"` before you continue or run the Docker Quickstart Terminal which does it for you...

Answer (score 8):

I knew that there are plenty of answers already in this post. Just I would like to add one simple answer that is solved the above mentioned problem .

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Run the above command and it will start all the docker related threads/services.

Answer (score 7):

Try adding the current user to `docker` group:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Then log out and login.

Answer (score 7):

Following Docker's DOC site: [Manage Docker as a non-root user](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#/install-the-latest-version)

1) Create Docker Group

```
sudo groupadd docker
```

2) Make user belong to docker group to get the group's privileges.

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Check whether the DOCKER_HOST environment variable is set for your shell.

```
env | grep DOCKER_HOST
```

If it exists,

```
unset DOCKER_HOST
```

Then this should work:

```
docker run hello-world
```

Comment: you are a life saver `unset DOCKER_HOST` worked for me

Comment: Two hours looking for this `unset DOCKER_HOST` solution. Thanks!

Comment: I had DOCKER_HOST set in my .zshenv, smh

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem - "Can't connect to docker daemon." (except I didn't get any 'file not found' errors on trying to start the server.)

'ps' showed that "/usr/bin/docker -d" was still running

I realised that I'd never actually succeeded in running the server myself though. Every attempt had produced

```
...
2014/03/24 21:57:29 pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid
```

So I belatedly realised that installing docker had maybe registered the daemon with upstart, which had started it for me. Hence, trying to kill the daemon to manually restart it fails (operation not permitted). So I did a

```
sudo kill -9 <PID>
```

on the daemon process. Another daemon immediately took its place, and this new one DOES now let my CLI client connect:

```
$ sudo docker info
Containers: 0
Images: 0
Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Dirs: 0
WARNING: No memory limit support
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Answer (score 6):

## LINUX

you can use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33596140/13997503
and even after using this you still get the same error. then you might have previously installed docker desktop and now switching to docker-engine

you can remove the docker desktop service files using this command

```bash
$ rm -rf ~/.docker
```

Comment: that's a great lesson to me that I should never copy & paste commands that I don't know from the internet, now I broke everything 

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same issue, running on [Amazon AWS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services).

Here's what I attempted:

- Set up `docker-machine` locally with already existing AWS instance
- Used generic setup
- It kind of connected, but since the remote port was closed, it failed
- After that, the Docker daemon refused to start up, but running `dockerd` did work...

It was tested following on the remote machine:

```
service docker start # Also restart, no success
systemctl start docker # Also restart, no success
dockerd # Success
```

I removed `/var/lib/docker` and uninstalled everything, but there was no success after reinstallation. Unfortunately I have no logs stored from failures, but `docker.service` just refused to start.

However, what finally solved my issue was basically:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)
```

Answer (score 4):

I got the same problem. In CentOS 6.5:

```
ps aux |grep `cat /var/run/docker.pid`
```

If it shows no Docker daemon process exists, then I type:

```
docker -d
```

Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to stop Docker. Because we use the `-d` option, Docker will run as daemon. Now we can do:

```
service docker start
```

Then I can do a `docker pull centos`. That's all.

NOTE: If these do not work, you can try `yum update`, and then repeat these again, because I `yum install` before these.

Comment: This step was important for me in diagnosing my docker problem after a hardlockup on my machine.  But the command I had to run to get this docker output was `sudo /usr/bin/dockerd` with no flags.  Ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 4):

If you are running on OS X using Docker tool, follow this.

Restart the daemon and configure your environment:

```
docker-machine restart
```

And then

```
docker-machine env
```

Finally,

```
eval $(docker-machine env)
```

To test the daemon is running:

`docker ps -a` or `docker-machine ls`. This will list all containers.

Answer (score 3):

The [Docker Service](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/) may not be running.

If you are on a RedHat/Fedora/CentOS, please try this:

`sudo systemctl start docker`

If you are on Ubuntu/Debian:

`sudo service start docker`

Docker will start running on your host and respective port.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this issue, I had to enable the docker service:

```
sudo systemctl enable /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix, you need to issue the following commands in the terminal. I'll explain each step:

```
# Uninstall Docker from apt packages
$ sudo apt-get remove docker docker.io

# Remove it from the libraries just to be
# sure it's gone forever
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/*
```

Now, if you want to simplify things and get more time, you can run my [`init` script](https://github.com/dminca/dotfiles/blob/master/init) with the parameter `installDocker`:

```
# Pull the init script from GitHub
$ wget https://github.com/dminca/dotfiles/blob/master/init

# Add rights to run the script
$ chmod 755 init

# Just run the script with the installDocker parameter
$ ./init installDocker
```

A reboot is optional, but I suggest you do it to be sure all runs smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are using Docker Machine :)

Run `docker-machine env default` should do the trick.

Because according to documentation:

> Docker Machine is a tool that lets you install Docker Engine on
>   virtual hosts, and manage the hosts with `docker-machine` commands. You
>   can use Machine to create Docker hosts on your local Mac or Windows
>   box, on your company network, in your data center, or on cloud
>   providers like AWS or Digital Ocean.
>
> Using `docker-machine` commands, you can start, inspect, stop, and
>   restart a managed host, upgrade the Docker client and daemon, and
>   configure a Docker client to talk to your host.
>
> Point the Machine CLI at a running, managed host, and you can run
>   `docker` commands directly on that host. For example, run 
>   `docker-machine env default` to point to a host called `default`, follow on-screen
>   instructions to complete `env` setup, and run `docker ps`, 
>   `docker run hello-world`, and so forth.

https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem running Docker 1.10 on Ubuntu 14.04 and none of the given answers worked. For me, the fix was to specify the storage driver when running the Docker daemon.

```
sudo docker daemon --storage-driver=devicemapper
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I also had the same issue. The problem was in sockets allocated to docker-daemon and docker-client.
2. First, permission was not set for the docker-client on docker.sock You can set it using "sudo usermod -aG docker $USER"
3. Then check your bash file where the docker-client is running, For me it was on 0.0.0.0:2375, while docker-daemon was running on unix socket.(It was set in the configuration file of dockerd).
4. Just comment the bash-line and it'll work fine.
5. But if you want to make it work on TCP port instead of unix socket, change the configuration file of dockerd and set it on 0.0.0.0.2375 and keep the line in bash as it is if present or set it to 0.0.0.0:2375.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.

In my case the solution was to remove a deprecated version of docker. This I assume was causing some conflicts.

On ubuntu:

```
sudo apt remove docker
```

solved the problem for me

Answer (score 1):

you can run the daemon with the following command:

```
sudo nohup docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock &
```

The script leaves the daemon running in the background, and with the Docker ready you can test that it is accepting commands.

```
sudo docker info
```

for more information check this out: 
https://www.upcloud.com/support/how-to-configure-docker-swarm/

Answer (score 1):

If you use gitlab-ci / gitlab-runners you get that error if you don't have permissions to access `/var/run/docker.sock`.

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

To solve the problem:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker gitlab-runner
```

Verify with:

```
sudo -u gitlab-runner -H docker info
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of answers already but in the hope that this helps someone. This is an issue that occurs when you install docker via snap. Running via sudo would allow you to connect to the daemon, but this leads to other issues. The solution is to perform some steps BEFORE you install the snap package making the complete list of steps:

```
sudo addgroup --system docker
sudo adduser $USER docker
newgrp docker
sudo snap install docker
```

After doing this, docker will connect to the daemon and work without sudo, no restart required.

https://github.com/docker-archive/docker-snap/issues/1#issuecomment-423778054

Answer (score 1):

My problem was, that default path of docker.sock was not where docker daemon was.

My default was /home/user/.docker, but docker daemon was in /var/bin.

i did set env variable to set correct address and that fixed the issue

```
export DOCKER_CONFIG = '/var/bin'
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/

I installed docker desktop on ubuntu so that might be the issue or why my DOCKER_CONFIG was not set right.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the Docker configuration file, `docker` or `docker-network` in `/etc/sysconfig`:

(... ~ v1.17)

#### `docker` file:

```
OPTIONS= -H fd://
```

or (v1.18):

#### `docker-network` file:

```
DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS= -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

**Have you tried turning it off and on again? :-)**

I had the same issue after upgrading to Docker 1.10.1 on my Mac.
I did the following:

On the Docker Quickstart Terminal

> $ exit
>
> $ exit

then

> docker-machine kill default

then restarted Docker Quickstart Terminal

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If regenerating TLS certificates doesn't work

```
docker-machine regenerate-certs default
```

Try restarting the docker machine and setting the env variable:

```
docker-machine restart default
eval $(docker-machine env default)
```

Check if the machine is running with:

```
docker-machine ls
```

or alternatively

```
docker run hello-world
```

This worked for me. However, if you still don't have the daemon up, [Docker's troubleshooting page](https://docs.docker.com/faqs/troubleshoot/) details a process for stopping, removing and creating a new machine.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the issue "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?".

I had forgot to use `sudo`. Hope it will help some of us.

```
$:docker images
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

$:sudo docker images
REPOSITORY   TAG   IMAGE ID   CREATED   SIZE
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I started having this problem today. Then I saw a lot of responses but none seem to have worked for me. First most of the instructions where directed to linux. And for the mac version they were all talking about running 'docker-machine'. I assume you use docker-machine if you install docker toolbox because then docker will be running in a virtual machine for windows and mac platforms. But its 2017 now and docker for mac is really stable hence no need for using the toolbox.

Not sure how the daemon stopped though. But to restart it all I had to do was go "Applications" and double click on the docker icon. I was asked to update and Relaunched which I accepted. After that everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac OS-X, this could just mean the docker installation is out-dated or not running. Simply download the latest docker from the offical site and install it.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

With Docker installed with `snap`, I sometimes encounter the OP's error upon rebooting my machine. In my case, running `sudo snap logs docker` revealed an error in the logs:

> Error starting daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/snap/docker/423/run/docker.pid

After running `sudo rm /var/snap/docker/423/run/docker.pid`, I can start Docker normally.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this never happens. But one day the message appeared (as bellow) and a simple reboot fixed it

`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

Answer (score 0):

well you can set the Docker CLI to use the local Docker daemon as the current context:

> docker context use default

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: run bleow command in terminal 1 same server.

`sudo dockerd`

Step 2: in terminal 2 same server.

`docker ps`

It should resolved