# Can't connect to docker from docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I installed docker-machine 0.1.0 and docker-compose 1.1.0 on Mac OS 10.8.5.
Docker-machine is running normally and able to connect by docker-machine ssh.

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM
dev    *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
```

However can't connect from docker-compose.

```
$ docker-compose up
```

> Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+unix://var/run/docker.sock - is it running?
>
> If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.

My Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml is here.

Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:centos7
DOCKER_HOST tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
```

docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  build: .
```

Why can't connect? Any ideas?

Comment: Does `docker-machine` run as root?  I just came here with the same problem on Ubuntu and it was the permissions on the socket - `sudo` did the trick.

Comment: For those on Linux, you might [just need to be added to the docker group](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33596140/434961).

Comment: just run : sudo docker-compose up

Comment: I had the same issue. You need to restart docker. `sudo service docker restart` or `sudo service docker start` I solved it with this.

Comment: For those using Ubuntu, you should use sudo and you **should not add users to the docker group**. View the comments in the accepted answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo

Comment: try `sudo chown $USER:docker /var/run/docker.sock`

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The Docker machine is running. But you need to export some environment to connect to the Docker machine. By default, the `docker` CLI client is trying to communicate to the daemon using `http+unix://var/run/docker.sock` (as shown in the error message).

Export the correct environment variables using `eval $(docker-machine env dev)` and then try again. You can also just run `docker-machine env dev` to see the environment variables it will export. Notice that one of them is `DOCKER_HOST`, just as the error message suggests you may need to set.

Comment: You can put that command (`eval "$(docker-machine env default)"`) in your bin/postactivate to ensure it's always up-to-date.

Comment: Where do I find the file bin/postactivate ?

Comment: Or you forgot to install docker:  ```$ eval $(docker-machine env dev)

Command 'docker-machine' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo snap install docker```

Answer (score 350):

Simple solution for me:   `sudo docker-compose up`

---

UPDATE 2016-3-14:  At some point in the docker install process (or docker-compose ?) there is a suggestion and example to add your username to the "docker" group.  This allows you to avoid needing "sudo" before all docker commands, like so:

```
~ > docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
root@665d1ea76b8d:/# date
Mon Mar 14 23:43:36 UTC 2016
root@665d1ea76b8d:/# exit
exit
~ >
```

Look carefully at the output of the install commands (both docker & the 2nd install for docker-compose) and you'll find the necessary step.  It is also documented here:  https://subosito.com/posts/docker-tips/

> **Sudo? No!**
>
> Tired of typing sudo docker everytime you issue a command? Yeah, there
>   is a way for dealing with that. Although naturally docker is require a
>   root user, we can give a root-equivalent group for docker operations.
>
> You can create a group called docker, then add desired user to that
>   group. After restarting docker service, the user will no need to type
>   sudo each time do docker operations. How it looks like on a shell
>   commands? as a root, here you go:

```
> sudo groupadd docker
> sudo gpasswd -a username docker
> sudo service docker restart
```

> Done!

## UPDATE 2017-3-9

## Docker installation [instructions have been updated here.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall/)

## Post-installation steps for Linux

This section contains optional procedures for configuring Linux hosts to work better with Docker.

**Manage Docker as a non-root user**

The docker daemon binds to a Unix socket instead of a TCP port. By default that Unix socket is owned by the user root and other users can only access it using sudo. The docker daemon always runs as the root user.

If you don’t want to use sudo when you use the docker command, create a Unix group called docker and add users to it. When the docker daemon starts, it makes the ownership of the Unix socket read/writable by the docker group.

To create the docker group and add your user:

```
# 1. Create the docker group.
$ sudo groupadd docker

# 2. Add your user to the docker group.
$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER

# 3. Log out and log back in so that your group membership is re-evaluated.

# 4. Verify that you can run docker commands without sudo.
$ docker run hello-world
```

This command downloads a test image and runs it in a container. When the container runs, it prints an informational message and exits.

Comment: Likewise for some reason sudo is the only way to get it working :O :O :O

Comment: Instead of logging out ... you can use command: `newgrp docker`

Comment: Re: "Simple solution for me: `sudo docker-compose up`". When I try that, I get: `sudo: docker-compose: command not found`

Comment: this works for me. after adding my user to the group `docker` I could run applications.

Answer (score 71):

If you started docker using `sudo` , then you should run docker-compose up with `sudo`
Like: `sudo docker-compose up`

Comment: It worked for me when I ran ```sudo docker-compose build``` instead of ```docker-compose build```.

Answer (score 64):

I solved the issue in Ubuntu 20.0.4 by

```
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

and then

```
sudo service docker start && docker-compose up -d
```

[Ref.](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4181)

Comment: Wrong answer. Do more research. You are giving everyone access to the socket.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo

Comment: @LiveWireBT It's the solution, has solved the problem. Could explain what's the best practice here?

Comment: Thank you very much. I was starting to pull out my hair

Comment: This solved my issue is 666 a bad thing for the socket ?

Comment: this solved my issue thanks

Answer (score 32):

When you get an **Error**:

> ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost -
>   is it running?

The **Solution** would be:

1. First, try verifying **Docker Service is Up and Running** as expected on your remote/local machine:`sudo service docker status`

   if Not - run `sudo service docker start`  or `sudo systemctl start docker` (depends on some linux versions, see Docker [get started instructions](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/)).
2. Second, start docker **as sudo** `sudo docker-compose up`

Answer (score 31):

By default the docker daemon always runs as the root user, therefore you need to prepend `sudo` to your Docker command(s).

If you don’t want to use sudo when you use the docker command, create a Unix group called docker and add users to it. When the docker daemon starts, it makes the ownership of the Unix socket read/writable by the docker group.

#### To create the docker group and add your user:

1. Create the docker group.

   `$ sudo groupadd docker`
2. Add your user to the docker group.

   `$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`
3. Log out and log back in so that your group membership is re-evaluated.
4. Verify that you can docker commands without sudo.

   `$ docker run hello-world`

This command downloads a test image and runs it in a container. When the container runs, it prints an informational message and exits.

The steps outlined above comes from the [official Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall/#/manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user).

Comment: How we can do this on windows installed Docker ?

Comment: Besides that, what I did to fix docker-compose was setting the user executing `docker-compose` as the owner of `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose` and then restart de service

Comment: `group` membership can be refreshed with `su - $USER` to save logging off & on

Answer (score 19):

`sudo systemctl start docker`
 - to start the Docker service.

`sudo docker-compose up` after that.

I have Fedora 26, and trying to solve the same issue I eventually entered [Docker Compose on Fedora Developers' page](https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tools/docker/compose.html) and then [Docker on Fedora Developers' page](https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tools/docker/docker-installation.html), which helped me.

Probably, docker service considered by community to start with the system and run in background all the time, but for me it was not so obvious, and that's the reason I can think of why there's no popular answer like this one.

On the [Fedora Developers' page](https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tools/docker/docker-installation.html) there's instruction how to enable Docker to start with the system:

`sudo systemctl enable docker`

Comment: Replace `systemctl` with `launchctl` if you're running on mac.

Answer (score 12):

a quick way to solve this

> Just add sudo before your docker command, like

```sh
sudo docker-compose up
```

Answer (score 9):

if you are using linux

try `sudo docker-compose up`

Answer (score 8):

Run this as a root. `sudo docker-compose up --build`

Comment: worked on Ubuntu 20.0 . Thank you

Answer (score 7):

If you are on Linux you may not have `docker-machine` installed since it is only installed by default on Windows and Mac computers.

If so you will need to got to: https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/ to find instructions for how to install it on your version of Linux.

After installing, retry running `docker-compose up` before trying anything listed above.

Hope this helps someone.  This worked for my devilbox installation in Fedora 25.

Answer (score 5):

while running `docker-compose pull` - i was getting below error

> ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost

is it running?

solution -

```
sudo service docker start
```

issue resolved

Answer (score 5):

I know it's silly, but in my case I just tried with `sudo` and it worked like a charm.

in your case, just try: `$ sudo docker-compose up`

Answer (score 5):

Easy way to fix this issue:
**Question:**
[image]

**Solution:**

```
sudo chown $USER /var/run/docker.sock
```

**Answer:**
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Anyone checked log ?

In my case error message in `/var/log/upstart/docker.log` was:

```
Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock) 
[graphdriver] using prior storage driver "aufs" 
Running modprobe bridge nf_nat failed with message: , error: exit status 1 
Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default "bridge" network: can't find an address range for interface "docker0"
```

Worth to mentioned I had vpn turned on, so:

`$ sudo service openvpn stop
$ sudo service docker restart
$ docker-compose up|start
$ sudo service openvpn start`

was the solution.

Comment: Yeah, this was the case for me too, but in case someone doesn't like this solution, here are some other solutions as well which do not require stopping/restarting the vpn service: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43720339/docker-error-could-not-find-an-available-non-overlapping-ipv4-address-pool-am

Answer (score 4):

if you are using docker-machine then you have to activate the environment using **env**  variable.
incase you are not using docker-machine then run your commands with **sudo**

Answer (score 4):

Apart from adding users to docker group, to avoid typing `sudo` repetitively,  you can also create an alias for `docker` commands like so:

```
alias docker-compose="sudo docker-compose"
alias docker="sudo docker"
```

Answer (score 4):

There might be privilege issues, Following command work out for me.

sudo chown $USER /var/run/docker.sock

Thanks to Max for solution: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60282354/revisions

Answer (score 3):

Answer from @srfrnk works for me.

In my situation, I had the next docker-compose.yml file:

```
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: "./docker/nginx.staging/Dockerfile"
    depends_on:
      - scripts
    environment:
      NGINX_SERVER_NAME: "some.host"
      NGINX_STATIC_CONTENT_OPEN_FILE_CACHE: "off"
      NGINX_ERROR_LOG_LEVEL: debug
      NGINX_BACKEND_HOST: scripts
      NGINX_SERVER_ROOT: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./docker-runtime/drupal/files:/var/www/html/sites/default/files:rw
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

`./docker-runtime` owner and group - is `root` when the other files owner - my user.
When I tried to build `nginx`

```
Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?
```

I added `./docker-runtime` to `.dockerignore` and it is solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
1 . sudo service docker stop 
2 . sudo service docker status
3 . sudo service docker start
4 . docker-compose build <app_name\service_name>
```

Comment: steps 1-3 and then also `docker-compose pull` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same symptoms.

Only diff that it happened only during `docker-compose build`
`docker ps` worked.
Happened with version `2.x` as well as `3.x`.
Restarted `docker` service, then the machine...
Even re-installed `docker` + `docker-compose`.

Tried everything but nothing helped.

Finally I tried building the Dockerfile "manually" by using `docker build`.

Apparently I had a permission issue on a file/folder inside the `Docker` context. It was trying to read the context when starting the build and failed with a proper error message.
However this error message **did not** propagate to `docker-compose` which only shows `Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+unix://var/run/docker.sock - is it running?`

Having found that the solution was simply adding the file/folder to the `.dockerignore` file since it wasn't needed for the build. Another solution might have been to `chown` or `chmod` it.

Anyway maybe this could help someone coming across the same issue that really has nothing to do with `docker` and the misleading error message being displayed.

Comment: I had the same problem: file permissions in a mounted volume. In my case I had an SSL cert that was owned by root that had been put in a Docker volume. `chown` / `chmod` fixed it. Terrible error message but they're working on it. See  https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5318

Answer (score 2):

**$sudo docker-compose up**

I did follow the steps as it is in the above answer to add $USER to group docker. i didn't want to add a new group docker because in my docker installation a group named docker automatically created.

[Docker CE is installed and running. The docker group is created but no users are added to it. You need to use sudo to run Docker commands. Continue to Linux postinstall to allow non-privileged users to run Docker commands and for other optional configuration steps.](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/)

but using docker-compose up didn't work either. It gave the same previous error.
So in my case(Ubuntu 18.10) sudo docker-compose up fixed the issue.

ps: @Tiw thanks for the advice.

Comment: Maybe it's better put the solution first, and those explaining below it. Also you can make use those buttons on the editor to format your answer better.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue using following steps

```
$ sudo service docker status
$ sudo service docker start
$ sudo docker-compose up
```

now docker-compose up is working

Answer (score 1):

logging out then in again helped me. In my case it was fresh install, I created a new user, new group then added the user to the docker group.

exit
exit

then ssh into the server again

Answer (score 1):

**WORKING!!**
I tried with below commands and its working

```
service docker restart
docker-compose -f docker_compose.yaml down
docker-compose -f docker_compose.yaml up
```

Answer (score 1):

A Solution that worked with me was to change the image tag to lowercase letters.

change the image tag in docker-compose.yml file to include repository IP and image name in lowercase letters.

e.g : image: 192.168.1.5/imagename:v1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: _Since I cannot edit at the moment:_
In the docker-compose.yml, one of the fields under a service is called `image`, which tells docker-compose what name to give to the docker image of the service when building.

If you put uppercase letters on the `image` field, Docker tells you that it can't connect to the Docker daemon, which is a very misleading message.
You can check what the problem actually is by running `sudo service docker status`

Answer (score 1):

`sudo dockerd` started the docker service in my case, I was using wsl2 in windows.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I started upgrading Docker and cancelled midway. I didn't notice that Docker was not running (if it was, there is an icon at the top nav bar of my Macbook, by the battery remaining, time, etc). Once I launched it, and finished the upgrade, `docker-compose up` worked again!

Answer (score 0):

My setup has got two cases for this error:

- `__pycache__` files created by root user after I run integration tests inside container are inaccessible for docker (tells you original problem) and docker-compose (tells you about docker host ambiguously);
- `microk8s` blocked my port until I stopped it.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `dockerd` or `sudo dockerd`if required first to start daemon. If you start `dockerd` with `sudo` you may want to run `docker-compose up` with `sudo` also. otherwise it's fine.

Working solution from https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4181

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, I'm not sure what part did the trick:

```
julian:project$ sudo service docker status
julian:varys$ sudo service docker status                                                                                                                                                                                
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-07-15 01:21:16 UTC; 24min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 6762 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 25
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           └─6762 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

julian:project$ export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock

julian:project$ sudo groupadd docker
groupadd: group 'docker' already exists
julian:project$ sudo gpasswd -a $USER docker
Adding user ubuntu to group docker
julian:project$ newgrp docker

julian:project$ ls -ln /var/run/ | grep docker
drwx------  5   0   0  120 Jul 15 01:10 docker
-rw-r--r--  1   0   0    4 Jul 15 01:10 docker.pid
srw-rw----  1   0 999    0 Jul 15 01:10 docker.sock

julian:project$ sudo rm /var/run/docker.sock                                                                                                                                                                                            
julian:project$ sudo rm /var/run/docker.pid

julian:project$ sudo service docker restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your docker environment using:

```
systemctl restart docker
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker Compose needs **privilege access**, make sure to provide the one before running the **docker-compose** command.

You may need to kill the current Docker process and restart the Docker Desktop, then it works most likely.

P.S. I am on MacOS and getting the same error as above after restarting and providing the root access to Docker Desktop (version 4.10.1) application I am able to run the docker compose command successfully as below.

> docker-compose up -d --build