# Docker "ERROR: could not find an available, non-overlapping IPv4 address pool among the defaults to assign to the network"

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have a directory `apkmirror-scraper-compose` with the following structure:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── privoxy
│   ├── config
│   └── Dockerfile
├── scraper
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── newnym.py
│   └── requirements.txt
└── tor
    └── Dockerfile
```

I'm trying to run the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  privoxy:
    build: ./privoxy
    ports:
      - "8118:8118"
    links:
      - tor

  tor:
    build:
      context: ./tor
      args:
        password: ""
    ports:
      - "9050:9050"
      - "9051:9051"

  scraper:
    build: ./scraper
    links:
      - tor
      - privoxy
```

where the `Dockerfile` for `tor` is

```
FROM alpine:latest
EXPOSE 9050 9051
ARG password
RUN apk --update add tor
RUN echo "ControlPort 9051" >> /etc/tor/torrc
RUN echo "HashedControlPassword $(tor --quiet --hash-password $password)" >> /etc/tor/torrc
CMD ["tor"]
```

that for `privoxy` is

```
FROM alpine:latest
EXPOSE 8118
RUN apk --update add privoxy
COPY config /etc/privoxy/config
CMD ["privoxy", "--no-daemon"]
```

where `config` consists of the two lines

```
listen-address 0.0.0.0:8118
forward-socks5 / tor:9050 .
```

and the `Dockerfile` for `scraper` is

```
FROM python:2.7-alpine
ADD . /scraper
WORKDIR /scraper
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "newnym.py"]
```

where `requirements.txt` contains the single line `requests`. Finally, the program `newnym.py` is designed to simply test whether changing the IP address using Tor is working:

```
from time import sleep, time

import requests as req
import telnetlib


def get_ip():
    IPECHO_ENDPOINT = 'http://ipecho.net/plain'
    HTTP_PROXY = 'http://privoxy:8118'
    return req.get(IPECHO_ENDPOINT, proxies={'http': HTTP_PROXY}).text


def request_ip_change():
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet('tor', 9051)
    tn.read_until("Escape character is '^]'.", 2)
    tn.write('AUTHENTICATE ""\r\n')
    tn.read_until("250 OK", 2)
    tn.write("signal NEWNYM\r\n")
    tn.read_until("250 OK", 2)
    tn.write("quit\r\n")
    tn.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dts = []
    try:
        while True:
            ip = get_ip()
            t0 = time()
            request_ip_change()
            while True:
                new_ip = get_ip()
                if new_ip == ip:
                    sleep(1)
                else:
                    break
            dt = time() - t0
            dts.append(dt)
            print("{} -> {} in ~{}s".format(ip, new_ip, int(dt)))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Stopping...")
        print("Average: {}".format(sum(dts) / len(dts)))
```

The `docker-compose build` builds successfully, but if I try `docker-compose up`, I get the following error message:

```
Creating network "apkmirrorscrapercompose_default" with the default driver
ERROR: could not find an available, non-overlapping IPv4 address pool among the defaults to assign to the network
```

I tried searching for help on this error message, but couldn't find any. What is causing this error?

Comment: Are there other containers running? They are probably in conflict (do `docker ps`)

Comment: No, `docker ps` shows no containers running.

Comment: What Is your `docker version` ?

Comment: The Docker version is `17.04.0-ce` (both `Client` and `Server`).

Comment: Do you have a VPN connected? Also, have you tried restarting your compueter? (I am googling) https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30295

Comment: Can you try `docker network ls` and confirm if networks were already created on your host.

Comment: [Robert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1094246/robert), I've restarted my computer and even ran the script [docker-nuke](https://gist.github.com/n3r0-ch/30c628813b67190d309d) but to no avail. [Peter Hauge](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5040699/peter-hauge), yes, with `docker network ls` I do see an entry with `NAME` `host` and `DRIVER` `host` (even after `docker-nuke`). Do I need to remove it?

Comment: i had accidentally created 30 or so bogus networks, which `ls` revealed to me! thanks @PeterHauge

Comment: Thanks @Robert I had PIA VPN running, once I disconnected and exited, it worked.

Comment: @Robert, in my case was the VPN. Disabling it, solved the issue.

Comment: I resolved my problem with: sudo service docker restart

Comment: `docker network prune`. This will resolve your issue

Comment: It turns out, this is not Python related, and OpenVPN is very often the cause (I refer to the question's tags).

Comment: [Docker Can Only Create 31 Default Networks](https://medium.com/@loomchild/docker-can-only-create-31-default-networks-e7f98f778626)

Comment: how do i stop services associated with a network?

Comment: I have a lot of containers. If I can't prune networks how do I get more?

Comment: I came across this same issue while running the docker-compose of ELK stack with WireGuard VPN running in the background. Disabling VPN worked in my case.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Following [Peter Hauge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5040699/peter-hauge)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43720339/docker-error-could-not-find-an-available-non-overlapping-ipv4-address-pool-am#comment74485284_43720339), upon running `docker network ls` I saw (among other lines) the following:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                                    DRIVER              SCOPE
dc6a83d13f44        bridge                                  bridge              local
ea98225c7754        docker_gwbridge                         bridge              local
107dcd8aa889        host                                    host                local
```

The line with `NAME` and `DRIVER` as both `host` seems to be what he is referring to with "networks already created on your host". So, following https://gist.github.com/bastman/5b57ddb3c11942094f8d0a97d461b430, I ran the command

```
docker network rm $(docker network ls | grep "bridge" | awk '/ / { print $1 }')
```

Now `docker-compose up` works (although `newnym.py` produces an error).

Comment: Doesn't work in more recent docker versions- they've disallowed removing built-in networks (such as `default`)

Comment: If you're using Traefik, make sure to shut down that container before running this command. Otherwise it will think all of your networks are active.

Comment: if I run `docker network rm $(docker network ls | grep "bridge" | awk '/ / { print $1 }')`I get `Error response from daemon: bridge is a pre-defined network and cannot be removed`on Ubuntu 20.04 `Docker version 19.03.9, build 9d988398e7` `docker-compose version 1.25.0, build unknown`

Answer (score 602):

I've seen it suggested docker may be at its maximum of created networks. The command `docker network prune` can be used to remove all networks not used by at least one container.

My issue ended up being, as [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1094246/robert) commented about: an issue with openvpn `service openvpn stop` 'solved' the problem.

Comment: If you need to run docker alongside vpn here is possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45692255/7918.

Comment: OpenVPN Service was the issue for me.

Comment: To add to the above answer, if you get any issue like this pruning the system can really help. `Docker system prune` can also be a fix, but please be careful, this can remove your DB, only use this if you don't care for you DB, or if your DB container is running then this command is safe as it only prunes things not being used by at least one container.

Comment: Thanks. I confirm that to stop the openvpn client will work. I had started it few days ago, then I ran the docker-compose today and got that error.

Comment: [Docker Can Only Create 31 Default Networks](https://medium.com/@loomchild/docker-can-only-create-31-default-networks-e7f98f778626)

Comment: Imagine a life where our tools give us useful debugging information.

Comment: For anyone who still has the issue after stopping VPN and running `docker network prune`, you may have to restart your PC. That solved it for me!

Comment: yes, it solved for me too, but how can we have openvpn running and still not get this error?

Comment: I had the same problem having a NordVPN connection active. I disconnected from the VPN and reconnected after launching the docker containers.

Answer (score 250):

I ran into this problem because I had OpenVPN running. As soon as I killed OpenVPN, `docker-compose up` fired right up, and the error disappeared.

Comment: Same here with another VPN provider (expressvpn).

Comment: The same problem with running OpenVPN

Comment: So I had the same issue and I'm wondering why this is happening. Why does Docker networking get confused when connected to a VPN.

Comment: I had the same problem with Private Internet Access

Comment: PIA uses OpenVPN.

Comment: Same issue with OpenVPN

Comment: I've added routes rather than `redirect-gateway def1` to get around the issue without killing my openvpn service.

Comment: Same problem when using PIA VPN.

Comment: same thing when running globalprotect on ubuntu

Comment: same problem because because I had VPN called `globalprotect` from paloaltonetworks running. As soon as I disconnect VPN the error disappeared. After the docker network is created you can enable your VPN again.

Comment: same problem with Speedify VPN v9.9.0.8564 on Ubuntu 20.04. I don't think I saw this issue on Ubuntu 18.04 whilst running Speedify though.

Comment: Same with Cisco Anyconnect on Ubuntu

Comment: GlobalProtect causes same issue.

Answer (score 174):

I ran in this problem with OpenVPN working as well and I've found a solution where you should NOT stop/start OpenVPN server.

Idea that You should specify what exactly subnet you want to use. In `docker-compose.yml` write:

```
networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.16.57.0/24
```

That's it. Now, `default` network will be used and if your VPN did not assign you something from `172.16.57.*` subnet, you're fine.

Comment: This is great! My server box can't stand without OpenVPN so advices on (even temporarily) disabling VPN are all nonsense to me.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, as simply killing VPN is stupid

Comment: Isn't 172.177.57.0/24 a routed newtork?  If so, it could cause problems contacting a limited number of hosts on the internet.

Comment: yep, a glitch here. Would be better to use one from `172.16.*.*` subnet

Comment: I don't think that using `172.177.57.*` is a good idea, because it not in the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_addresses. Use addresses within this range.

Comment: Thanks so much for this solution! I need to run `docker-compose` with NetScaler (`nsgclient` on Ubuntu) VPN enabled, because various scripts in our docker images make requests to servers within our corporate network. This does the trick for me.

Comment: This worked. I tried `docker network prune` but it didn't help then I noticed this answer. Disconnecting with vpn worked immediately.

Comment: Facing the same error message I soled it with the command: `docker network create -d bridge --subnet 172.16.57.0/24 roachnet`

Answer (score 67):

I have the same problem. I ran `docker system prune -a --volumes`, `docker network prune`, but neither helped me.

I use a VPN, I turned off the VPN and, after it docker started normal and was able to create a network. After that, you can enable VPN again.

Comment: My VPN connection was on the same subnet as the one docker was trying to use. Disconnecting solved the problem for me. :)

Comment: Also, solve for me after off the open vpn connection.

Comment: Careful with `docker system prune -a --volumes` , next time, you launch Docker Compose, it will have to redownload all volumes

Answer (score 56):

## TL;DR

Add

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    ...
    network_mode: bridge
```

[Read about `network_mode` in the
documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode).

## Long version

*Disclaimer*: I am not very knowledgeable about Docker networking, but this did the trick for me. YMMV.

When I ran `docker run my-image` the networking gave me no problems, but when
I converted this command to a `docker-compose.yml` file, I got the same error
as the OP.

I read [Arenim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56136591/2521769) and
some other stuff on the internet that suggested to re-use an existing network.

You can find existing networks like this:

```
# docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
ca0415dfa442        bridge              bridge              local
78cbbda034dd        host                host                local
709f13f4ce2d        none                null                local
```

I wanted to reuse the default `bridge` network, so I added

```yaml
services:
  web:
    ...

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: bridge
```

to the the *root* of my `docker-compose.yml` (so not inside one of my
`services`, but at the root indentation).

I now got the following error:

> ERROR: for your-container network-scoped alias is supported only for
> containers in user defined networks

This led met to [this Docker Github
issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3012), that plainly stated
that I should add the `network_mode` object to my `docker-compose`:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    ...
    network_mode: bridge
```

This was tested on Docker version `18.09.8`, `docker-compose` version `1.24.1` and the compose file format `3.7`.

Comment: is this a question or an answer?

Comment: More a: my adventures in Docker-network land and how I stumbled onto something that stuck.

Comment: Not everyone wants to use the bridge network

Answer (score 42):

As other answers mentioned, Docker's default local `bridge` network only supports 30 different networks (each one of them uniquely identifiable by their name). If you are not using them, then `docker network prune` will do the trick.

However, you might be interested in establishing more than 30 containers, each with their own network. Were you interested in doing so then you would need to define an `overlay` network. This is a bit more tricky but extremely well documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay-standalone.swarm/).

EDIT (May 2020): Link has become unavailable, going through the docs there's not an exact replacement, but I would recommend starting from [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/).

Answer (score 36):

Same error occurred while running VPN connection. Tried to create docker image with docker-compose.
Works for me to stop VPN connection for a moment and execute the command.

Comment: Confirmed here. You saved me from starting running unknown commands.

Comment: One more here... Running the Cisco Anyconnect drive me to this problem. +1

Answer (score 29):

If you want lots of networks, then you can control how much IP space docker hands out to each network via the `default-address-pools` daemon setting, so you could add this to your `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{
  "bip": "10.254.1.1/24",
  "default-address-pools":[{"base":"10.254.0.0/16","size":28}]
}
```

Here I've reserved `10.254.1.1/24` (254 IP addresses) for the bridge network.

For any other network I create, docker will partition up the `10.254.0.0` space (65k hosts), giving out 16 hosts at a time (`"size":28` refers to the [CIDR mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing), for 16 hosts).

If I create a few networks and then run `docker network inspect <name>` on them, it might display something like this:

```
   ...
   "Subnet": "10.254.0.32/28",
   "Gateway": "10.254.0.33"
   ...
```

The `10.254.0.32/28` means this network can use 16 ip addresses from `10.254.0.32` - `10.254.0.47`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Restarting the docker service is required after making the changes to `/etc/docker/daemon.json`.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer instead of  ``` docker network prune ``` or re-configuring the default bridge in the compose which are not scalable. In this case, pool can always be added.

Answer (score 27):

Answer is sometimes : docker network prune

Comment: Perhaps add a bit more details to this answer as to what the problem is and how this command solves it. Otherwise, it seems to get lost in the scrollfest because it is very short :D

Comment: This solution fixed it!

Answer (score 20):

**Killing the vpn is not needed.**

This other [comment about using a new network comes pretty close to the solution for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56136591/293492), and was working for a while, but [I found a better way thanks to some talk over in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692255/how-make-openvpn-work-with-docker)

Create a network with:

```
docker network create your-network --subnet 172.24.24.0/24
```

Then, at the bottom of docker-compose.yaml, put this:

```
networks:
  default:
    external: 
      name: your-network
```

Done.  No need to add networks to all container definitions etc.  and you can re-use the network with other docker-compose files as well if you'd like.

Answer (score 13):

I had an identical problem with the same error message but the solution with removal of unused docker networks didn't help me. I've deleted all non-default docker networks (and all images and containers as well) but it didn't help - docker still was not able to create a new network.

The cause of the problem was in network interfaces that were left after OpenVpn installation. (It was installed on the host previously.) I found them by running `ifconfig` command:

```
...
tun0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
      inet addr:10.8.0.2  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:75 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
      RX bytes:84304 (84.3 KB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

tun1  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
      inet addr:10.8.0.2  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:200496 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:148828 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
      RX bytes:211583838 (211.5 MB)  TX bytes:9568906 (9.5 MB)
...
```

I've found that I can remove them with a couple of commands:

```
ip link delete tun0
ip link delete tun1
```

After this the problem has disappeared.

Comment: This worked for me after trying several options - stopped openvpn, restarted pc, reinstalled docker, network prune, etc...

Answer (score 13):

You can try

```
$sudo service network-manager restart
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

1. Check if any other container is running, If yes, do: `docker-compose down`
2. If VPN is connected, then disconnect it and try again to up docker container:

   ```
   docker-compose up -d container_name
   ```

Comment: I've no VPN running but `docker-compose down` fixed it for me

Answer (score 10):

```
docker network prune
```

Worked fine for me in Sep, 2022, over ubuntu 20 server.

Answer (score 9):

I encoutered the same problem, the reason why is that you reached the max of networks:

do an : `docker network ls`
Choose one to remove using: `docker network rm networkname_default`

Answer (score 9):

I had this error when a VPN was running on my system. As soon as I disconnected the VPN, docker was up and running.

Answer (score 8):

This happened to me because I was using `OpenVPN`. I found a way that I don't need to stop using the VPN or manually add a network to the docker-compose file nor run any crazy script.

I switched to `WireGuard` instead of `OpenVPN`. More specifically, as I am running the nordvpn solution, I installed WireGuard and used their version of it, NordLynx.

Comment: The specific command to switch from OpenVPN to the WireGuard protocol for NordVPN is `nordvpn set technology NordLynx`.  It is not a separate product, and currently is only available on Linux & iOS.

Comment: Thank you for this! It worked perfectly and no additional installs were required for me, just running `nordvpn set technology NordLynx` did the trick.

Answer (score 8):

Very good explanation of this issue is on this [link](https://straz.to/2021-09-08-docker-address-pools/).

As short the issue was appeared because the default Docker daemon has small IP addresses pool.
And this issue can be solved by config `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with the next content:

```
 {
  "default-address-pools" : [
    {
      "base" : "172.17.0.0/12",
      "size" : 20
    },
    {
      "base" : "192.168.0.0/16",
      "size" : 24
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem

*Creating network "schemaregistry1_default" with the default driver

  ERROR: could not find an available, non-overlapping IPv4 address pool among the defaults to assign to the network*

and nothing helped until I turned off the Cisco VPN. 
after that docker-compose up worked

Comment: Thank you so much @Вячеслав Калякин! Turning Off VPN solved my case as well.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a lot of networks in `docker network ls` you need to run `docker system prune -f`

This line removes unused data, unused images and all unused local volumes. I have it in my crontab:

```
# cleanup docker
0 3 * * * /usr/bin/docker system prune -f;/usr/bin/docker image prune -a --filter "until=24h" -f; /usr/bin/docker volume prune -f
```

Comment: I'd be careful with this. This is a destructive crontab to have.

Comment: Thanks @AdamKDean, I added a disclaimer.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue on a corporate development VM which wasn't running OpenVPN.  Checking out `etc/docker/daemon.json`, I found

```
...
"default-address-pools": [
  {
    "base": "192.168.11.0/24",
    "size": 24
  }
],
...
```

Strangely, removing the `default-address-pools` field and then restarting docker with `sudo systemctl restart docker` fixed the issue for me.  I'm assuming this let docker choose a more suitable default, but I don't know what the problem was with the chosen default.

Answer (score 3):

I ran in this problem because of forcepoint vpn addresses.

> 1 - check your in use addresses using `nmcli` command

> 2 - choose a non overlapping CIDR address (x.x.x.x/xx) #google for details

> 3 - `docker container prune` #to destroy all created container

> 4 - `docker network prune` #to destroy all created networks

> 5 - modify (or create if not present) `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and add the follwing entry (changing eventually the address with your choosed one):

```
{
    "default-address-pools":[
        {
            "base":"173.5.0.0/16",
            "size":24
        }
    ]
}
```

N.B. be careful using 173.x.x.x because it is'n a private address and may cause problem if you need to go to an external address pointing to the same ip but it is one solution when your vpn already take control of all other internal ips

> 6 - `sudo systemctl restart docker`

> 6.error - If the service doesn't start it may be caused by another overlapping network.
>
> Use `journalctl -xe` to see the error.
>
> You can check again your networks using `nmcli` and retry.
>
> N.B. After too many retry you may need to reset error count `sudo systemctl reset-failed servicename.service`

Comment: same thing for me, vpn blocks docker compose start, this the only solution that works :3

Answer (score 1):

I found this problem with one of enterprise network I was working with. The specific requirement was not be use the default from docker 172.17.0.0/16 and 172.18.0.0/16.

Private IP4 network, such as 10.28.160.0/24 and 10.28.161.0/24 was supposed to be used which I configured in docker daemon and it was resulting in non-overlapping issue. Changing subnet mask to /16 such as 10.28.160.0/16 solved the issue. It clearly provided more number of hosts and thus polling easily achieved.

Comment: Worked for me with Docker Desktop and Cisco VPN. This helped me understand what this change does: https://straz.to/2021-09-08-docker-address-pools/

Answer (score 1):

I restarted my NetworkManager in Ubuntu and it resolved

Answer (score 1):

docker network prune. This works fine.

Comment: This answer does not add anything to the existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

Running the `docker network prune` command did't help me.
I also use a VPN and can’t disable it because images for `docker-compose` are downloaded only through a VPN.

I added a non-overlapping address space to the file `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
# /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "default-address-pools":[
    {
      "base":"173.5.0.0/16",
      "size":24
    }
  ],
  "experimental": true
}
```

I try to restart docker with command `sudo systemctl restart docker.socker`, but still not working.

After that I finded all application containers:

```bash
docker container ls -a | grep my-app-name
=>
0d55efcf2c69   ... my-app-name_postgres
9b73192fb131   ... my-app-name_redis
```

And delete all:

```bash
docker container rm 0d55efcf2c69
docker container rm 9b73192fb131
```

After restarting docker.socket, docker-compose started successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but in my case, it was because I had too many containers running (about 220).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had many docker networks in my system, so I listed all the docker networks by running the command `docker network ls`.

Then i removed one of the unwanted network by running the command `docker network rm {network_id}`.

Later i run `docker-compose up` command and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As many answers said, adding `default-address-pools` into daemon.json worked for me. Here I share how to do that easily in docker desktop assuming it helps someone who don't know how to do it.

As shown in below image follow the each steps in order.

1. Select settings in docker desktop.
2. Select Docker Engine from the side menu.
3. Edit the daemon.json file. You can edit it here.
4. Do Apply & restart.

Now run your container again.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

I fixed this issue by steps :

1. turn off your network (wireless or wired...).
2. reboot your system.
3. before turning on your network on PC, execute command docker-compose up, it's going to create new network.
4. then you can turn network on and go on ...

Comment: Indeed, just `reboot` my computer worked in my case, thanks !