# Error with pre-create check: "VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path"

Tags: docker, centos, virtualbox, docker-machine

i run CentOS in VirtualBox on physical Windows7. Now in centOS i have Docker and i need to run

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox host1
```

but i get error

```
Error with pre-create check: "VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path"
```

so do i need to install VirtualBox once again and in the CentOS? If yes, how can i do that?

thanks lot

Answer (score 38):

Yes you are absolutely correct. You need to install VirtualBox first of all.

You can do it by running  `yum install virtualbox`  for CentOS or 
 `sudo apt-get install virtualbox`  for Ubuntu

Do so and then run your code and you will be good to go

Comment: "yum install virtualbox " will it work for amazon linuz also ?

Comment: $ sudo yum install virtualbox
Loaded plugins: dkms-build-requires, priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main                                                                                                 | 2.1 kB  00:00:00
amzn-updates                                                                                              | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
No package virtualbox available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: If I got you correctly, you want to install virtualbox on aws ec2?

Answer (score 17):

It's an issue with permissions. You've installed docker as sudo. You need to run

```
sudo docker-machine create --driver virtualbox host1
```

OR

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

to get around this.

Comment: sudo docker-compose up worked for me, did not have to try the first one

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same error in Ubuntu 18.04 but I realized that I had installed docker-machine using command : `sudo snap install docker`.

However install docker-machine using :

```
$ curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.13.0/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` >/tmp/docker-machine && \
chmod +x /tmp/docker-machine && \
sudo cp /tmp/docker-machine /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

Check your installation :

```
$ docker-machine version
```

Then install virtualbox using :

```
$sudo apt install virtualbox
```

Now you can create the docker-machine using the command :

```
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox dev
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Error with pre-create check: "VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path"

Answer (score 4):

Being more specific about install VirtualBox on Mac Mojavi.

1. After downloading the VirtualBox-6.0.6-130049-OSX.dmg, double-click to install
2. Go to your applications folder and you will find the virtualbox.pkg like this:

   [image: virtualbox.pkg]
3. Click on it to complete the installation.
4. After install is complete, you should see VirtualBox in the applications folder like this:

   [image: virtual box after installation completes]
5. Afterwards you should refresh your terminal and rerun your command.

   ```
   docker-machine create --driver virtualbox local-docker.
   ```

Answer (score 2):

try to execute with superuser:

```
sudo docker-machine create -d virtualbox myvm1
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who are using windows you can open the powershell command shell as an administrator and run the command below:

**PS C:\Windows/system32>** `choco install  virtualbox`

if you don't have choco you can install it using this the command below:

**PS C:\Windows/system32>**

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; `
      iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to install the virtualbox :

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox

then run this command:

docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
```

Comment: Error with pre-create check: "VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path"

Answer (score 1):

1. Reinstalled virtualbox

> sudo snap remove virtualbox && sudo snap install virtualbox

2. Renamed VBoxManage to match casing

> sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage /usr/local/bin/vboxmanage

3. Reinstall Docker Machine with the command below.

> ```
> base=https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.16.0 &&
>   curl -L $base/docker-machine-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) >/tmp/docker-machine &&
>   sudo mv /tmp/docker-machine /usr/local/bin/docker-machine &&
>   chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
> ```

4. Confirm the version and save scripts to /etc/bash_completion.d or /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d

```
base=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/machine/v0.16.0
for i in docker-machine-prompt.bash docker-machine-wrapper.bashdocker-machine.bash
do
  sudo wget "$base/contrib/completion/bash/${i}" -P /etc/bash_completion.d
done
```

5. Rerun the command.

> docker-machine create --driver virtualbox host1

Answer (score 0):

1) Reinstall Virtualbox ... you can use this code : sudo apt-get install virtualbox

2) sudo docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default

Answer (score 0):

Doing installation of Docker-Swarm using below steps:

```
$ base=https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.16.0 &&
  mkdir -p "$HOME/bin" &&
  curl -L $base/docker-machine-Windows-x86_64.exe > "$HOME/bin/docker-machine.exe" &&
  chmod +x "$HOME/bin/docker-machine.exe"
```

Steps with ERROR:

```
$ base=https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.16.0
$ mkdir -p "$HOME/bin"
$ curl -L $base/docker-machine-Windows-x86_64.exe > "$HOME/bin/docker-machine.exe"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   623  100   623    0     0   1236      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1238
100 27.2M  100 27.2M    0     0   726k      0  0:00:38  0:00:38 --:--:--  593k

$ chmod +x "$HOME/bin/docker-machine.exe"
$ docker-machine version
docker-machine.exe version 0.16.0, build 702c****
$ docker-machine ls
NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE   URL   SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS

$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox manager1
Creating CA: C:\Users\*****\.docker\machine\certs\ca.pem
Creating client certificate: C:\Users\*****\.docker\machine\certs\cert.pem
Running pre-create checks...
Error with pre-create check: "VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path"
```

Resolution:

Then I installed VM from below link:Install VirtualBox
Download VirtualBox and the corresponding Extension Pack: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads
Install VirtualBox with the default settings
Add the Extension Pack to VirtualBox (File -> Preferences -> Extensions)

```
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox manager1
Running pre-create checks...
Error with pre-create check: "This computer is running Hyper-V. VirtualBox won't boot a 64bits VM when Hyper-V is activated. 
Either use Hyper-V as a driver, or disable the Hyper-V hypervisor. (To skip this check, use --virtualbox-no-vtx-check)"
```

Then finally its created with below command:

```
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox  --virtualbox-no-vtx-check manager1
Running pre-create checks...
(manager1) Image cache directory does not exist, creating it at C:\Users\****\.docker\machine\cache...
(manager1) No default Boot2Docker ISO found locally, downloading the latest release...
(manager1) 0%....10%....20%....30%....40%....50%....60%....70%....80%....90%....100%

(manager1) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(manager1) Creating SSH key...
(manager1) Starting the VM...
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you installed virtualbox and vboxmanage on VM and still getting the same error:

Make sure your user is in the docker group. Otherwise you run docker as root and vbox as user and they can't see each other. Telltale sign that you're not in the group is that you have to sudo docker commands, e.g.:

```
sudo docker images
```

To fix, do:

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo gpasswd -a <your-username> docker
```

Now check that user is added:

```
getent group docker
```

or:

```
grep /etc/group -e "docker"
```

Also restart docker daemon:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Log out and back into terminal (try restarting system if this does not work), and you should be able to run docker without sudo, e.g.:

```
docker images
```

docker machine and docker-compose should now run, too.

Fore more information, refer to this answer: [Can't connect to docker from docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29101043/cant-connect-to-docker-from-docker-compose)

Answer (score 0):

Run below commands:

1. `sudo apt-get install virtualbox` To install virtual box and then.
2. also make sure docker machine is installed. [LINK](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/)
3. `docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default` to create machine & [link](https://docs.docker.com.zh.xy2401.com/v17.09/machine/get-started/#create-a-machine) for the same