# "VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path"

Tags: python, docker-compose, virtual-machine

I am trying to create selenium grid with docker using this post.
But when I am trying to create docker it is showing error.

Command used:

`docker-machine create -d virtualbox Grid`

Error msg:

> Error with pre-create check: "VBoxManage not found. Make sure
>   VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path"

When I run:
`which VBoxManage`
it shows location as: `/usr/bin/VBoxManage`

Comment: https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4590

Comment: I've got the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install virtualbox
```

The answer is posted  [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45836296/error-with-pre-create-check-vboxmanage-not-found-make-sure-virtualbox-is-inst)