# Running docker I got error : Bind address needs a port: 127.0.0.1

Tags: docker, ubuntu

After reinstalling my Kubuntu 18 I try to install docker-ce
and running app I got error :

```
$ docker-compose up
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
serge@AtHome:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/PerlerWealth/master$ export DOCKER_HOST=127.0.0.1
serge@AtHome:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/PerlerWealth/master$ docker-compose up -d --build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.17.1', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 68, in main
    command()
  ...
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/utils/utils.py", line 373, in parse_host
    "Bind address needs a port: {0}".format(addr))
docker.errors.DockerException: Bind address needs a port: 127.0.0.1
```

Why errors and how to fix this error ?

Related app versions and config info :

```
root@AtHome:~/Downloads# docker --version 
Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d
root@AtHome:~/Downloads# docker-compose --version 
docker-compose version 1.17.1, build unknown
root@AtHome:~/Downloads# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
root@AtHome:~/Downloads# docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 0
 Server Version: 19.03.13
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 8fba4e9a7d01810a393d5d25a3621dc101981175
 runc version: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd                                                                                                                                                                                      
 init version: fec3683                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 Security Options:                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  apparmor                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  seccomp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   Profile: default                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 Kernel Version: 4.15.0-20-generic                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 OSType: linux                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 Architecture: x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 CPUs: 4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 Total Memory: 7.711GiB                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 Name: AtHome                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 ID: FGEV:TTKB:COS7:VUEW:7C2T:UJWK:2L66:Y6UE:APLU:M5HG:R5DG:3RN7                                                                                                                                                                             
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 Debug Mode: false                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

**MODIFIED :**

```
root@AtHome:~/Downloads# docker --version
Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d
root@AtHome:~/Downloads# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
root@AtHome:~/Downloads# sudo  usermod -aG docker $USER
root@AtHome:~/Downloads# sudo  newgrp - docker
root@AtHome:/root# sudo systemctl enable docker 
Synchronizing state of docker.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable docker
root@AtHome:/root# sudo systemctl start docker
        
root@AtHome:/root# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

I have all /etc files from prior working installation, but which config
files have I to look at or some missing options or permissions lacking ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the `DOCKER_HOST` variable is used when you want to connect to a remote host (e.g. a server) from your client (e.g. your laptop). check the output of `docker --version` or `docker ps` to see if docker is running and if your user has the correct permissions.

Comment: Please look at MODIFIED

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50114623/8745763