# Docker socket at host for Docker Machine instance

Tags: macos, docker, homebrew

**TL;DR:** How do I create or link a Docker socket at `/var/run/docker.sock` at my host for a Docker Machine instance?

---

On my Mac, I installed Docker and Docker Machine using Homebrew:

```
brew install docker docker-machine
```

I also installed `docker-machine-driver-vmware` to create a Docker Machine instance based on my hypervisor:

```
brew install docker-machine-driver-vmware
docker-machine create --driver vmware default
```

My problem is that I have an application that relies on the Docker socket to create containers, but I cannot find the Docker socket anywhere in my system.

How do I find the Docker socket, and how can I change it or link it to `/var/run/docker.sock`?

Comment: If you're using Docker Machine, there's not a Unix socket on the host; you need to make a TCP connection to the VM.  See for example [Can't connect to docker from docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29101043/cant-connect-to-docker-from-docker-compose).  The standard Docker SDK understands the `$DOCKER_HOST` environment variable and other settings to make this connection.  (The Docker Desktop application could be simpler to use, if you don't have other reasons for specifically wanting this VM setup.)

Comment: @DavidMaze using `eval $(docker-machine env default)` (which configures `DOCKER_HOST` along with other environment variables for instance `default`) works well for cases that you want to interact with Docker from the shell instead of the socket, which is what most applications use to interact with Docker.

Comment: I made my question more general to appeal to more people.