# Docker not starting " could not delete the default bridge network: network bridge has active endpoints""

Tags: linux, docker, debian

Any ideas how to fix it?

```
Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: could not delete the default bridge network: network bridge has active endpoints
```

**OS**: Debian 8
**Docker version**: 1.9.0, build 76d6bc9

**ifconfig output**:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:3f:49:a0:9d:b4  
      inet addr:192.168.0.104  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::e23f:49ff:fea0:9db4/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:5231 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:4651 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:3019389 (2.8 MiB)  TX bytes:858951 (838.8 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5568 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5568 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:330007 (322.2 KiB)  TX bytes:330007 (322.2 KiB)
```

Comment: Do you have running docker containers? Stop them.

Comment: Looks like nothing is running:
```docker ps
Error response from daemon: 404 page not found```

Comment: Sigh... you should be concerned when you see the word "error", not assume all is ok. Your docker is not working correctly. It shouldn't return a 404. Have you configured your docker to use a remote daemon or something? This can be set with an environment variable.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart
I've already tried to reinstall it - no result. 
All was working out of the box but after reboot docker daemon don't want to start.
```systemctl start docker returns```  error.

Comment: What error is it returning?

Comment: ```Job for docker.service failed. See 'systemctl status docker.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.```
Journalctl - https://bitbucket.org/snippets/linevich/7EkBj

Comment: I have no idea. I would uninstall docker, reboot, and re-install.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I had a similar issue after upgrading.

Run

```
sudo mv /var/lib/docker/network/files/ /tmp/dn-bak
```

to reset your networks. Then restart docker (`sudo systemctl restart docker` or `sudo service docker restart` depending on your OS).

If everything works again you can delete the `dn-bak` directory.

Comment: Followed by a `sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart`:)

Comment: Thanx! Saved my day. Also works on Hypriot image for RPi.

Comment: I found that a Docker restart was sufficient to fix this issue, even without moving/deleting the network.

Comment: It works for me But i want to know the reason why i have to face this error?

Comment: Thanks. I was facing the same issue with vagrant

Answer (score 0):

Just restarting docker was enough. As @schmunk mentioned

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart
```