# Rails, Docker: Host does not exist: "default"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

When I try to run `docker-machine start default` , I get `Host does not exist: "default"`, I tried `eval "$(docker-machine env default)"`, but still getting the same message. Where is the error ?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try simply to check what machine has been created ([`docker-machine ls`](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/ls/)):

```
docker-machine ls
```

Then you can pick one  and try your commands with it.

If there is none, you can create one first ([`docker-machine create`](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/)).
In the case of the OP:

```
docker-machine create default
```

Since the error message was:

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

One of the answers of "[Docker command can't connect to docker daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33562109/6309)" should work:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Comment: i get `Running pre-create checks...
Error creating machine: Error with pre-create check: VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path
`, should i install Virtual box ?

Comment: If you are on a Mac, yes.

Comment: No, i'm using ubuntu. But actually, i need just to run `docker-compose up`, but i get this `ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run docker-machine start default` Could you suggest me something ?

Comment: @VPaskar Try to follow https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2495#issuecomment-161764374

Comment: not my case, i've read many posts about this problem, but none of those was the solution

Comment: @VPaskar no proxy at all?

Comment: @VPaskar What `docker info` and `docker env` return?

Comment: `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?` - docker info, `docker: 'env' is not a docker command.` - docker env

Comment: @VPaskar Sorry `docker version`

Comment: @VPaskar would one of the answers of http://stackoverflow.com/a/34024801/6309 help?

Comment: `Client:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 13:16:54 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?` - the lastest

Comment: @VPaskar Try again the installation:  `wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/gpg | sudo apt-key add -` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/33636041/6309). If not, what restarting the server return? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/33562183/6309)

Comment: I restarted the docker servise, and now it works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @VPaskar Great! I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibilty.

Answer (score 39):

you may try:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox default
```

**UPDATE 2016/10/19**

The old answer may only work on mac with virtualbox installed.

If you are running docker-machine on windows, you should use Hyper-V :

```
docker-machine create --driver hyperv vm
```

see detail here:https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/

And if you are using Docker Machine to provision hosts on cloud providers, you may need other driver such as amazonec2 . More detail:https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started-cloud/

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: Sorry, I got it. And wil do better nexttime.

Comment: First tried Docker for Mac -- no go. Tried this after so many other options and thanks!

Comment: I have ubuntu 14.04
I fire above command  get following error
"Error with pre-create check: "VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path"

Comment: @Rajnik   yeah. I use docker-machine on my mac .
I am not sure why you are using it on ubuntu .  
see here:https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/

And if you really want to run it on ubuntu , you may need to get VirtualBox installed.

Comment: For Windows 10 users, make sure when executing that you're console / powershell is started as an Administrator.

Comment: Not "only work on mac" for sure - it worked on Ubuntu with VirtualBox installed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In case you run

```
docker-machine ls
```

and it lists `default` but running `docker-machine kill default` and `docker-machine stop default` both complain that it doesn't exist, try to remove it completely and setup again:

```
docker-machine rm default
docker-machine create default
```

(had this weird issue on Windows with virtualbox)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, `docker-machine start default` might misbehave and require you to rerun the command again. In that case, running `eval "$(docker-machine env default)"` will bring back joy :)