# Can't run Ecplise Che under ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, docker, eclipse-che

I would like to install Eclipse Che IDE on a remote ubuntu 14.04 server. Here is what I did:

1. opened a SSH session from my laptop to the ubuntu server, logged-in as "useradm"
2. followed [this URL](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/) to install docker
3. in /home/useradm/ I downloaded a TAR.GZ file from [here](https://www.eclipse.org/che/download/)
4. ran `bin/che.sh -i run`, got this:

```
Starting Che server in docker container named che.
A Docker container named che does not exist or duplicate conflict was discovered.
Cleaning up any zombie containers named che...
Pulling the Docker image labeled codenvy/che:latest...
latest: Pulling from codenvy/che
72b39c1d4615: Pull complete 
46a2d5ede4a6: Pull complete 
d7caf6e91ad4: Pull complete 
c7ac9f284354: Pull complete 
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete 
622afa89a87c: Pull complete 
5f4e252666a5: Pull complete 
8302e51d25eb: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:19a8b73c5349604d746b3ad27dd78d4fbdb32933ab496e1f1b3ed77928cea355
Status: Downloaded newer image for codenvy/che:latest
Launching a new Docker container named che from image codenvy/che:latest...
e504a0ba54f87b4dd4a5b417ce540c3f43084818fb677b40f4c5e8f90669f002
Docker container named che successfully started.
Launching Che in a container named che...
sudo: unable to send audit message: Operation not permitted
bash: line 1:    10 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) sudo rm -rf /home/user/che/lib-copy/*
```

5. found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33562109/docker-command-cant-connect-to-docker-daemon): launched this

```
sudo usermod -aG docker useradm
logout
```

6. opened new SSH session, ran `bin/che.sh -i run` again, got this:

```
############## HOW TO CONNECT YOUR CHE CLIENT ###############
After Che server has booted, you can connect your clients by:
...
15:04:36,897 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[file] - File property is set to [null]
15:04:36,899 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[file] - Failed to create parent directories for [/home/user/che/tomcat/logs/2016/05/26/catalina-0.log]
...
2016-05-26 15:04:38,608[ost-startStop-1]  [ERROR] [o.a.j.EmbeddedServletOptions 692]    - The scratchDir you specified: /home/user/che/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/dashboard is unusable.
...
2016-05-26 15:04:42,025[main]             [INFO ] [o.a.c.http11.Http11NioProtocol 514]  - Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2016-05-26 15:04:42,026[main]             [INFO ] [o.a.c.http11.Http11NioProtocol 529]  - Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

What's wrong with my steps ? :(

From my browser, http://172.16.16.11:8080/ is working fine:

`This is the default Tomcat home page. It can be found on the local filesystem at: /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/index.html`

Do I have to move Che files from /home/useradm/ to /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/ or not ?

**UPDATE**: I ran `bin/che.sh run` (without any parameter), I got this :

```
[ERROR] [o.a.c.http11.Http11NioProtocol 460]  - Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

8080 port is used by tomcat, should I stop tomcat service ?

**UPDATE**: I was right :) I stopped tomcat:

`sudo service tomcat7 stop`

And I got this:

```
############## HOW TO CONNECT YOUR CHE CLIENT ###############
After Che server has booted, you can connect your clients by:
1. Open browser to http://localhost:8080, or:
2. Open native chromium app.
#############################################################
...
Server startup in 6151 ms
```

But http://172.16.16.11:8080 still shows tomcat home page, not Che interface !? Is it normal message when it's showing "http://localhost:8080" and not the server IP ?

**UPDATE** It was a browser cache problem, I stopped Che, reloaded http://172.16.16.11:8080, 404, I run Che again and now it's ok :)

Answer (score 0):

The right steps were:

1. untar file in ANY folder
2. install JRE 8 :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

3. check java version : `java -version`, here what I got:

```
useradm@modlamp01:~/eclipse-che-4.0.1$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

4. Set JAVA_HOME variable :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH` 
WARNING : you have to point to the folder witch contains le "lib" one, to find your java install folder use this : `readlink -f $(which java)
```

5. Make sure 8080 port is free
6. run this: `bin/che.sh run` with no parameters, in case of problems this command shows errors