# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I have installed docker on ubuntu 14.04, it told me installed successfully. Then I entered `sudo docker version`, it returned

```
Client:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 13:12:04 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

I entered `sudo service docker status`, I got

```
docker start/running, process 8063
```

I tried `sudo docker images` and `sudo docker info`, I got the same reply:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

I do not know why it returned this, I tried to pull ubuntu using `sudo docker pull ubuntu`, and got

```
Using default tag: latest
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

Please tell me how can I solve this problem, how can I pull and run docker image. And is `docker -d` the same as `docker deamon`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker can't connect to docker daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871479/docker-cant-connect-to-docker-daemon)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to add your current user to `docker` group like following:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker <your username>
```

Also, you can use `USER` environment variable like:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Then restart the system. As the docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#create-a-docker-group) says:

> The *docker* daemon binds to a *Unix socket* instead of a *TCP port*. By default that
>   Unix socket is owned by the user *root* and other users can access it
>   with `sudo`. For this reason, docker daemon always runs as the root
>   user.
>
> To avoid having to use `sudo` when you use the `docker` command, create a
>   Unix group called `docker` and add users to it. When the docker daemon
>   starts, it makes the ownership of the Unix socket read/writable by the
>   `docker` group.

Comment: I got the same output on ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but setting `sudo usermod -aG docker <your username>` with my username didn't worked. After rebooting my system I get still `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?` the same. Any idea?

Comment: Same for me: ubuntu 14.04 LTS, sudo usermod ..etc... didn't work while sudo docker ps works...

Comment: @chrx Did you restart the system? Also you can test ps06756 solution

Comment: yes i did try both to logout/login and to restart the machine, but nothing changed

Answer (score 8):

If adding user to the `docker` group doesn't work then try restarting the service:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Answer (score 6):

The only way that worked for me (on ubuntu xenial):

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo gpasswd -a ${USER} docker
sudo service docker restart
newgrp docker
```

Found [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/17645)

Comment: This worked for me, while the other answer for adding docker group did not.

Answer (score 1):

In my case working answer is

```
$ docker-machine create -d virtualbox default
$ eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

Comment: this is for MacOS, but is no longer applicable as of 2017

Answer (score 1):

Am not sure if others have used this approach, but when I face this issue of "Is the docker daemon running on this host?", Unsetting docker related environment variables helps recognize the docker daemon running on my machine. The same error message shows up when I open a new tab in the terminal window and unsetting has helped resolve it.

```
unset ${!DOCKER_*}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the other solutions above don't work you can try checking the ownership of `/var/run/docker.sock`:

```
ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
```

If you're not the owner then change ownership with the command:

```
sudo chown *your-username* /var/run/docker.sock
```

Then you can go ahead and try executing the Docker commands hassle-free :D

Comment: What if I couldn't find **docker.sock** on ***/var/run/***?

Comment: if `docker.sock` is missing, try running `sudo service docker stop` and then `sudo service docker start`

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers here fixed my issue, so i'm posting my solution here in case it helps anyone. This command fixed the issue for me:

`$ docker context use default`

Answer (score -1):

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

If it's showing this error please check your typecode:

```
->   docker build -t swagger-ui-builder .
```

is correctly given. If miss some value show error .

Refer to this site: http://swagger.io/swagger-ui/