# Docker deamon seams to start, but isn't listet in running processes

Tags: linux, docker

I'm trying to run docker (on a linux vm) using [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#configure-docker-to-start-on-boot) instruction.
The whole installation process worked fine until subpoint 4/5 of Installation.
When running `sudo service docker start` I get a message like `docker start/running, process 3072` but running `sudo docker run hello-world` gives.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo docker run hello-world
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

also when listing the processes with `ps -A`

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ ps -A
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:01 init
    2 ?        00:00:00 kthreadd
    3 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/0
    5 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:0H
    7 ?        00:00:00 rcu_sched
    8 ?        00:00:00 rcuos/0
    9 ?        00:00:00 rcu_bh
   10 ?        00:00:00 rcuob/0
   11 ?        00:00:00 migration/0
   12 ?        00:00:00 watchdog/0
   13 ?        00:00:00 khelper
   14 ?        00:00:00 kdevtmpfs
   15 ?        00:00:00 netns
   16 ?        00:00:00 writeback
   17 ?        00:00:00 kintegrityd
   18 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   19 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u3:0
   20 ?        00:00:00 kblockd
   21 ?        00:00:00 ata_sff
   22 ?        00:00:00 khubd
   23 ?        00:00:00 md
   24 ?        00:00:00 devfreq_wq
   27 ?        00:00:00 khungtaskd
   28 ?        00:00:00 kswapd0
   29 ?        00:00:00 vmstat
   30 ?        00:00:00 ksmd
   31 ?        00:00:00 fsnotify_mark
   32 ?        00:00:00 ecryptfs-kthrea
   33 ?        00:00:00 crypto
   45 ?        00:00:00 kthrotld
   65 ?        00:00:00 deferwq
   66 ?        00:00:00 charger_manager
  108 ?        00:00:00 kpsmoused
  109 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_0
  110 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u2:2
  130 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u2:3
  176 ?        00:00:00 jbd2/sda1-8
  177 ?        00:00:00 ext4-rsv-conver
  183 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:2
  462 ?        00:00:00 upstart-udev-br
  468 ?        00:00:00 systemd-udevd
  545 ?        00:00:00 dhclient
  643 ?        00:00:00 rpcbind
  697 ?        00:00:00 rpc.statd
  702 ?        00:00:00 upstart-socket-
  780 ?        00:00:00 rpciod
  786 ?        00:00:00 nfsiod
  819 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
  857 ?        00:00:00 rpc.idmapd
  888 ?        00:00:00 systemd-logind
  918 ?        00:00:00 rsyslogd
  947 ?        00:00:00 upstart-file-br
 1107 tty4     00:00:00 getty
 1110 tty5     00:00:00 getty
 1114 tty2     00:00:00 getty
 1115 tty3     00:00:00 getty
 1117 tty6     00:00:00 getty
 1152 ?        00:00:00 sshd
 1154 ?        00:00:00 acpid
 1155 ?        00:00:00 cron
 1156 ?        00:00:00 atd
 1275 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u3:1
 1480 ?        00:00:00 puppet
 1515 ?        00:00:00 ruby
 1548 tty1     00:00:00 getty
 1576 ?        00:00:00 kauditd
 2165 ?        00:00:00 sshd
 2172 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:1
 2219 ?        00:00:00 sshd
 2220 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 3429 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$
```

does not show the previously started process.

Using the [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34471074/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-is-the-docker-daemon-running-on-this-host) command

```
 sudo usermod -a -G docker vagrant
```

doesn't change anything.
running `docker version` returns

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.10.3
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   20f81dd
 Built:        Thu Mar 10 15:54:52 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

Can anybody suggest anything?

Comment: Can you run docker container without `sudo`?

Comment: @Cortwave Not sure if that's what you mean but, the response of `docker run hello-world` is exactly the same as with `sudo`.

Comment: Generally, if a service is failing to start, the first place to look is in your system logs to see if there are any messages there indicating why the service failed.

Comment: Why not use the simple method as in https://docs.docker.com/linux/step_one/

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by simply using the [instruction](https://docs.docker.com/linux/step_one/) suplied by @warmoverflow in the comments. I still don't know why it didn't work before but it's probably not worth wasting time on.