# Have to set up eval $(dinghy env) everytime. Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

Tags: docker

I installed dinghy, docker on mac os x.
If I try this, it works:

```
$dinghy up
Starting the dinghy VM...
Starting NFS daemon, this will require sudo
Password:
Waiting for NFS daemon...
Mounting NFS /Users/xxxx
Starting the FsEvents daemon
Starting DNS and HTTP proxy
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
   VM: running
  NFS: running
 FSEV: running
PROXY: running
```

Then try to start docker either (docker-compose up)or(docker ps), the message shows:

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on
>   this host?

Problem solves when I try:

```
eval $(dinghy env)
```

But I shouldn't have to do this every time when I open new console, I didn't in last environment. According to the site here I also tried:
[Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34471074/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-is-the-docker-daemon-running-on-this-host)

```
$sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

But it shows:

> sudo: usermod: command not found

Please let me know how I can solve this, so I don't have to set `eval $(dinghy env)` everytime.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried the new [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/)? It solves a lot of problems things like Dinghy was created for.

Comment: Thanks @ldg, I am currently working on something else, I will try this whenever I get a chance!

Comment: I have the same issue. I have to manually run `eval $(dinghy env)` every time I open a new console. So infuriating.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`, add there `eval $(dinghy env)` and it executes that `eval` for each new session.