# Docker build: Cannot Connect to Docker Daemon

Tags: docker, docker-image

I've been trying to follow this [tutorial](https://tutorialedge.net/golang/go-docker-tutorial/) on containerizing golang applications with docker. However, I ran into trouble once I tried to build the docker image. When I ran this command: `docker build -t my-go-app .` in my terminal I got an error:

```
time="2020-10-07T10:00:53-07:00" level=error msg="failed to dial gRPC: cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker daemon' running on this host?: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:2376: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34471074/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-is-the-docker-daemon-running-on-this-host)

Comment: The `192.168.99.100:2376` address suggests a Docker Toolbox or Docker Machine setup; is the Docker VM running?  Can you edit your question to include a [mcve] showing the code and other setup that produces this error?

Comment: @decky-g you can check if Docker is running by executing `docker info` from your command line. Do you have Docker installed? If not follow the steps
[here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/) for mac, and
[here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#:~:text=To%20start%20Docker%20Desktop%2C%20search,accessible%20from%20any%20terminal%20window.) for windows.