# ps command cannot connect to the docker daemon even after adding user to docker group

Tags: docker

I have started a docker container using the following command

```
     vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ docker run -t -i ubuntu /bin/bash
     root@abb8ef669ab6:/# cd
```

I am able to see the container shell. However, I am not able to list the docker processes in the new shell on the host using docker ps. am I missing something here?

```
     vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo usermod -aG docker vagrant
     vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ docker ps -a
     Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

Comment: I just tested this! It didn't work

Comment: edited the question!

Answer (score 2):

I suppose here is the problem solution
"It is neccesary add user to docker group"
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33596140/2313177

Comment: I just tested this! It didn't work.