# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon when running with sudo

Tags: macos, docker

My Docker service is up and running. However when attempting to use Docker by running it with `sudo`, e.g.:

```
12:40:26/~ $ sudo docker pull fluxcapacitor/pipeline
Using default tag: latest
```

I have got the following error:

```
Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Cannot connect to 
the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?). Using system 
default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

Note that I had already followed the answers on [Mac OS X sudo docker Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193300/mac-os-x-sudo-docker-cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-is-the-docker-daemon-r)

as follows:

**docker-machine start default**

```
12:40:36/~ $ docker-machine start default
Starting "default"...
Machine "default" is already running.
```

**docker ps**

```
12:41:20/~ $ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

So what more needs to be done?

This is:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 1.11.2, build b9f10c9
```

on `El Capitan`.

Output of `docker-machine env default`

```
$ eval "$(docker-machine env default)"

$ docker-machine env default
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/macuser/.docker/machine/machines/default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot connect to the Docker daemon on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084846/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-on-macos)

Comment: @kenorb Your mistake is discussing on meta https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365735/my-question-was-marked-as-possible-duplicate-even-though-i-had-already-addressed

Comment: Also related: [Docker can't connect to docker daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21871479/55075), the accepted answer got same answer with 'eval' method, but I understand this is for macOS, other for Linux, however it's the same thing in terms of the resolution.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I've misread your question, as 'Cannot connect to the Docker daemon' error happens when there is the problem with Docker installation, so re-installing it from Cask would potentially help. However in your case, your Docker installation was fine, but the issue was related with `sudo`, so I've clarified your post and retracted the vote.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following command exports a few environment variables that the subsequent docker commands use:

```
eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

However, if you launch docker with sudo, the exported environment variables are not accessible by the docker executable. You could potentially get it to work by passing `-E` flag to `sudo`, e.g.:

```
sudo -E docker pull fluxcapacitor/pipeline
```

But much easier option is to use docker without root like:

```
docker pull fluxcapacitor/pipeline
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set environment variables with:

```
eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

More about it [here](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/).

Comment: ah yes I had neglected to mention in OP that had been performed. But for good measure did it again. No change in behavior (same error)

Comment: @javadba What is the output of "docker-machine env default"?

Comment: @khattam  Updated OP with that info.

Comment: @khattam  Cha ching. Care to write up an answer?

Comment: I'll give an upvote for getting the discussion rolling but @khattam gets awarded.

Answer (score 1):

I had same probelem on my MAC, when attempted

```
# eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

got this error

```
Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs: There was an error validating certificates for host "192.168.99.100:2376": x509: certificate is valid for 192.168.99.101, not 192.168.99.100
You can attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate-certs [name]'.
```

to regenerate certificates, find out the docker-machines available;

```
# docker-machine ls
```

Output of avalable docker machines (omitted others)

```
NAME          ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default       -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           Unknown   Unable to query docker version: Get https://192.168.99.100:2376/v1.15/version: x509: certificate is valid for 192.168.99.101, not 192.168.99.100
```

Generate certificates for this default docker-machine

```
# docker-machine regenerate-certs default
```

and then setup docker-machine env to `default` docker-machine;

```
# eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

and it works normally after that.

Answer (score 1):

I have also tried the same but did not work.

later I have tried these steps on AWS CLI

```
$ sudo nano /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
"dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]
}
$ sudo service docker restart
$ docker pull hello-world
```