# Docker works but deamon is not responding

Tags: docker, maven, junit, testcontainers

Could you help me with this interesting case:

my docker creates images and runs containers fine
**BUT**
when I'm trying to run tests from testcontainers with command

```
docker run -it --rm -v $PWD:$PWD -w $PWD -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock my-image:1.0 mvn test
```

I receive

> Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime
> create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process:
> exec: "mvn": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

Comment: What's in the Dockerfile that builds `my-image:1.0`; does it contain a `mvn` binary anywhere in the path?

Comment: My Dockerfile

FROM openjdk:8

WORKDIR /app

COPY .mvn/ .mvn
COPY mvnw pom.xml ./
RUN ./mvnw dependency:resolve

COPY src ./src

CMD ["./mvnw", "spring-boot:run"]

Comment: here is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74173489/docker-socket-is-not-found-while-using-intellij-idea-and-docker-desktop-on-macos/74185395#74185395