# Failed Test in Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus

I am getting this error while build , what could be the reason?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you did not run gitlab-runner with /var/run/docker.sock mounted as a (file) volume?

See [this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/1035):

> Make sure to use:

```
docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always \
 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
 -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner \
 gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

See "[Run gitlab-runner in a container](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/install/docker.md)"

Comment: docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?.
See 'docker run --help'.

Comment: @sunshine that is a good question. Is docker running? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/33596140/6309)