# Brew install docker does not include docker engine?

Tags: macos, docker, homebrew

Trying to setup docker from brew, however the engine does not seem to be included in any of the any of the official formulas.

```
brew install docker-machine docker-compose
```

So these only installs the clients?
Is there no keg with the engine/daemon?

Answer (score 331, accepted):

Please try running

```
brew install docker
```

This will install the Docker engine, which will require Docker-Machine (+ VirtualBox) to run on the Mac.

If you want to install the **newer** [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/), which [does not require virtualbox](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/), you can install that through Homebrew's Cask:

```
brew install --cask docker 
open /Applications/Docker.app
```

Comment: 'docker-compose' up just gives me: an error 

"you might need to run docker-machine start default"

I do not want to run a virtual box for my containers, I want to run it locally on my mac

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to install Docker for Mac, which does not require VirtualBox or Docker-Machine.

Comment: I can see that this gives me the entire desktop app. Is there no way to get the daemon+cli tools only, I want to run it on a "headless" OSX.

Comment: For running Docker on macOS, you either need Docker-Machine (+ VirtualBox), or the "native" Docker for Mac (which internally starts a small VM as well from what I understand).

Comment: @DavidKarlsson The GUI app is the "official" Docker app, Docker Inc. provies no headless package for Mac OS. However, the GUI app contains the command line utilities. If the `brew cask install docker` does not create symlinks in `usr/local/bin` you can create them yourself: `ln -s /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin /usr/local/bin/docker`

Comment: @chiborg -- thank you for that extra tidbit regarding the symbolic link, definitely needed!

Comment: But this is the command-line that worked for me: `ln -s /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker /usr/local/bin/`

Comment: It is not necessary to create the symbolic links to docker binaries manually. Running Docker app for the first time creates these symbolic links. See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/43365425/303363 for details.

Comment: You need also `open /Applications/Docker.app` otherwise `docker` will just give `command not found`, I'll edit.

Comment: `brew cask install docker` is deprecated and `brew install docker` installs docker CLI. To install the docker for desktop, run `brew install --cask docker`

Comment: This worked for me as well, I just had to uninstall docker and docker desktop first, then reinstalling them and docker worked for me again

Comment: same; `brew uninstall docker && brew install --cask docker` worked for me.

Comment: is using brew to install docker really recommended or safe?

Comment: My experience with Docker Desktop is mixed. I got a daily nag from it which I think stopped when I shut off automatic updates. It also broke python. The docker-compose python was first on my path and broken when I run "python" from the command line. To get both docker-compose and python both working, I had to put docker-compose either at the start or end of my PATH. I created an alias for docker-compose in my .bashrc which altered the PATH before running it. The benefit of docker desktop is that it adds a thin UI on top of docker - and that they maintain a new version of docker.

Comment: Note that docker on the Mac (or Windows) runs 1 VM per container. This is fine for 1 container but could get heavyweight if you want to run 10 containers. Under Linux, each docker container runs in 1 process.

Comment: The link in your answer which is supposed to provide an explanation of why "Docker Desktop" (previously called "Docker for Mac" or "Docker for Windows") does not require VirtualBox actually mentions that it is incompatible with a certain older versions of VirtualBox. And as mentioned here: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/vm-vdi/  "... Docker Desktop is using a Linux VM in which it runs Docker Engine and the containers." So, it requires some kind of virtual machine hypervisor to run.

Answer (score 551):

The following steps work fine on macOS Sierra 10.12.4. Note that after brew installs Docker, the `docker` command (symbolic link) is not available at `/usr/local/bin`. Running the Docker app for the first time creates this symbolic link. See the detailed steps below.

1. Install Docker.

   ```
   brew install --cask docker
   ```
2. Launch Docker.

   - Press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to bring up *Spotlight Search* and enter `Docker` to launch Docker.
   - In the *Docker needs privileged access* dialog box, click *OK*.
   - Enter password and click *OK*.

   When Docker is launched in this manner, a Docker whale icon appears in the status menu. As soon as the whale icon appears, the symbolic links for `docker`, `docker-compose`, `docker-credential-osxkeychain` and `docker-machine` are created in `/usr/local/bin`.

   ```
   $ ls -l /usr/local/bin/docker*
   lrwxr-xr-x  1 susam  domain Users  67 Apr 12 14:14 /usr/local/bin/docker -> /Users/susam/Library/Group Containers/group.com.docker/bin/docker
   lrwxr-xr-x  1 susam  domain Users  75 Apr 12 14:14 /usr/local/bin/docker-compose -> /Users/susam/Library/Group Containers/group.com.docker/bin/docker-compose
   lrwxr-xr-x  1 susam  domain Users  90 Apr 12 14:14 /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-osxkeychain -> /Users/susam/Library/Group Containers/group.com.docker/bin/docker-credential-osxkeychain
   lrwxr-xr-x  1 susam  domain Users  75 Apr 12 14:14 /usr/local/bin/docker-machine -> /Users/susam/Library/Group Containers/group.com.docker/bin/docker-machine
   ```
3. Click on the docker whale icon in the status menu and wait for it to show *Docker is running*.

   [image]
   [image]

4. Test that docker works fine.

   ```
   $ docker run hello-world
   Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
   latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
   78445dd45222: Pull complete
   Digest: sha256:c5515758d4c5e1e838e9cd307f6c6a0d620b5e07e6f927b07d05f6d12a1ac8d7
   Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest

   Hello from Docker!
   This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

   To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
    1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
    2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
    3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
       executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
    4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
       to your terminal.

   To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
    $ docker run -it ubuntu bash

   Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
    https://cloud.docker.com/

   For more examples and ideas, visit:
    https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/

   $ docker version
   Client:
    Version:      17.03.1-ce
    API version:  1.27
    Go version:   go1.7.5
    Git commit:   c6d412e
    Built:        Tue Mar 28 00:40:02 2017
    OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

   Server:
    Version:      17.03.1-ce
    API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.12)
    Go version:   go1.7.5
    Git commit:   c6d412e
    Built:        Fri Mar 24 00:00:50 2017
    OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
    Experimental: true
   ```

Comment: This is great! Now I'm just stuck at User X isn't part of the docker group. What's the current way to fix that?

Comment: I'm stuck at Docker Desktop for Mac being tied to running with the user logged into the Mac OS UI. It's not possible to `open /Applications/Docker.app` remotely to start using docker. And if you do sign out, it stops the app and the engine and all its containers.

Comment: `brew cask install docker` command not work. it works `brew install homebrew/cask/docker` or `brew install --cask docker` docker install but its not showing in application by click command and space bar.

Comment: is using brew to install docker really recommended or safe?

Comment: this is a great answer, with a ton of transparency into the whole setup process. thank you!

Comment: Docker CLI tools are installed under $HOME/.docker/bin -- so `docker` is not available on the CLI by default. You can update your PATH or go to Docker Desktop settings -> Advanced -> select "System (Requires password)"

Comment: Install using `brew install --cask --no-quarantine docker` in order to disable macOS's Gatekeeper, which eliminates the dialog "Docker.app is an application downloaded from the internet. Are you sure you want to open it?"

Answer (score 48):

To install Docker for Mac with homebrew:

```
brew install homebrew/cask/docker
```

To install the command line completion:

```
brew install bash-completion
brew install docker-completion
brew install docker-compose-completion
brew install docker-machine-completion
```

Comment: you don't want `brew install docker` -- this is not the same as `brew cask install docker` and installs different things @mimoralea

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up: `brew cask install docker && brew install bash-completion docker-completion docker-compose-completion docker-machine-completion`

Comment: Don't use docker-machine - it will gives you a lot of headache with network forwarding

Comment: @mimoralea I would suggest you delete your first comment, so everyone spots your second one :-)

Comment: @IgorSerebryany why are they different? what is the difference between them? I would expect the docker daemon be there either way, and work cli - is the difference only that one (cask) has kitematic as well?

Comment: You should leave the completion related things to the Docker cask and not use these, in fact, if `docker-completion` or `docker-compose-completion` is installed beforehand, it will conflict with the cask. Just run `brew install --cask docker` and run `Docker.app`, it will deal with the completions itself.

Answer (score 13):

Docker desktop will not be installed if you run `brew install docker`. If you've already installed it this way, first uninstall with `brew uninstall docker`.

To install Docker Desktop, run:

```bash
brew install homebrew/cask/docker
```

Launch docker from your `/Applications` folder once and enter your password, then you can run commands like `docker --version` to verify the CLI is working.

Answer (score 12):

Docker Desktop for Mac is not a suitable choice for enterprise docker users as it requires a paid license to use. [Rancher Desktop](https://rancherdesktop.io) is a viable open-source alternative for Docker Desktop for all three major OS.

Since this question is specifically targeted at Mac OS users, I have added the steps to make it work on Mac OS.

1. First install Docker using homebrew.
   `brew install docker`
2. Install Rancher Desktop.
3. In `Kubernates Settings`, change container runtime to `dockerd`.

Profit !

UPDATE: There's another open-source container runtime in the scene, named Colima (https://github.com/abiosoft/colima).

Comment: Does Rancher replace the need for `docker-machine` and hence obviates the need for `virtualbox`?

Comment: @NeilG Yes it does.

Comment: Yes indeed. On an M1 Mac on version 12.4 Monterey the following commands worked: `softwareupdate --install-rosetta` - `brew install docker` - `brew install --cask rancher` - `open /Applications/Rancher\ Desktop.app/` - `docker run hello-world`. I chose "dockerd (moby)" as the container runtime. I'm not sure if rosetta is required. I had already installed it and wasn't able to check whether it was required or not.

Answer (score 5):

There is now alternative to Docker Desktop for Mac: [colima](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima)

If you have Homebrew installed, you can install it using:

```
brew install colima docker
colima start
```

`docker` installs Docker client, while `colima` provides the daemon.

Comment: To start it as a service, `brew services start colima`

Answer (score 2):

For reinstall docker, you should run:

```
brew reinstall homebrew/cask/docker
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, `brew uninstall docker && brew install --cask docker` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**[OrbStack](https://orbstack.dev/)** provides an unmodified Docker engine, and thus Docker CLI. I've been using it on my M2 Pro successfully.

```
% docker version
Client:
 Version:           24.0.6
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.7
 Git commit:        ed223bc
 Built:             Mon Sep  4 12:28:49 2023
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           orbstack

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.6
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.7
  Git commit:       1a79695
  Built:            Mon Sep  4 12:31:30 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.7.6
  GitCommit:        091922f03c2762540fd057fba91260237ff86acb
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.9
  GitCommit:        82f18fe0e44a59034f3e1f45e475fa5636e539aa
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```