# Docker, Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

Tags: docker

**MacOS Sierra** 10.12.2

**Docker** 1.12.5

New to Docker, this error appears every time I try to build a Docker file:

```
$ sudo docker build -t tutorial .
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

I followed the instructions from this SO post but the the problem wasn't solved:
[Docker can't connect to docker daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871479/docker-cant-connect-to-docker-daemon)

Docker version:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 1.12.5, build ...
```

The directory:

```
$ ls
Dockerfile  README.md   apache      supervisord
```

Start virtual machine for Docker:

```
$ docker-machine start
Starting "default"...
Machine "default" is already running.
...
$ docker-machine env
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.00.00:2576" #edit
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/myUser/.docker/machine/machines/default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
# Run this command to configure your shell: 
# eval $(docker-machine env)
...
$ eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

Run it again:

```
$ sudo docker build -t tutorial .
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

**SOLVED:** does works without `sudo`:

`$ docker build -t tutorial .`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try run this command `docker build -t tutorial .` without `sudo` or run `eval "$(docker-machine env default)"` with sudo

Comment: @user1644677 - `eval "$(docker-machine env default)"` creates some variables in your terminal session, but when you are using sudo you are login as another user (`root`), so, you haven't access to that docker variables.