# Docker warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon

Tags: windows, docker, docker-machine

On Windows 10, when I call a docker command:

```
docker pull mongo:windowsservercore
```

I get the following output:

```
Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.26/info: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.). Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
```

When I `docker-machine create default`

```
(default) Waiting for an IP...
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Too many retries waiting for SSH to be available. Last error: Maximum number of retries (60) exceeded
```

Comment: For Linux/Unix/macOS, see: [Docker can't connect to docker daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21871479/55075)

Answer (score 11):

I got the same error running Docker for Windows on Windows 10 Pro.  The solution was to open the Docker settings and turn on the Daemon.  Right-click on the taskbar icon and choose settings.  Then, turn on the daemon per the image below.

[image: Option To Choose]

Comment: I was getting this error when trying to run docker commands from a TeamCity build agent. Once I enabled this setting, everything started working correctly. Thanks!

Comment: After the Windows 10 October Update this setting was unchecked for some reason. I guess I should be happy this was the only thing I lost during the update 

Answer (score 10):

You probably use [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) OpenSource solution to have Docker running on Windows 10.
In that case, the reason is that your docker CLI cannot work without daemon.
Run the Docker daemon (you probably have an icon on your desktop) and once it reports that it is ready, try again your commands.

Comment: Not only Windows. Same happens on my Fedora 24. Can be fixed by running _dockerd_

Comment: @dbow the post states that the platform is Windows :)

Comment: What exactly is Docker "OpenSource solution"?

Comment: @JimAho You have two options to run Docker containers on Windows:

   1. Run Windows 2016 server with native support
   2. Install OpenSource solution "Docker for Windows" on Windows 10 or "Docker Toolbox" on Windows 7

Answer (score 3):

I just restarted docker on Windows from the tray icon, right-click, then "Restart".

Answer (score 2):

This got resolved for me and was able to install once Right Click Docker icon on task bar and clicked on "Switch to Windows Container"

Answer (score 1):

I am getting this error too. I had installed docker via the docker toolbox.
Had tried the docker windows installer but it said I needed the pro version
of windows 10 (had the win10 home version).

Anyways, if I run the commands via the Docker Quickstart Terminal, this problem goes away.
ie. use Docker Quickstart Terminal instead of your command prompt.