# Service docker start not work(daemon), ubuntu-15.10, To run dockerfile with intelliJ

Tags: linux, docker, intellij-idea, ubuntu-15.10

I have installed docker on ubuntu 15.10 but it does not start, these are the console outputs, I'm new with this from docker, try installing docker from this tutorial https://tecadmin.net/install-and-manage-docker-on-ubuntu/

**My interest is to be able to run my dockerfile from intellij**

**service docker start**

```
root@rubnPC:/var/lib/docker# service docker start
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error 
code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

**systemctl status docker.service**

```
root@rubnPC:/var/lib/docker# systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since sáb 2017-06-03 18:24:42 VET; 3min 
18s ago
Docs: https://docs.docker.com
Process: 21270 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, 
status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 21270 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

jun 03 18:24:42 rubnPC systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container 
Engine...
jun 03 18:24:42 rubnPC dockerd[21270]: time="2017-06-03T18:24:42.614560352-
04:30" le...id"
jun 03 18:24:42 rubnPC systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, 
code=exited,...URE
jun 03 18:24:42 rubnPC systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application 
Container Engine.
jun 03 18:24:42 rubnPC systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed 
state.
jun 03 18:24:42 rubnPC systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-
code'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

**journalctl -xe**

```
root@rubnPC:/var/lib/docker# journalctl -xe
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has begun starting up.
jun 03 18:24:42 rubnPC dockerd[21270]: time="2017-06-03T18:24:42.614560352-
04:30" level=fa
jun 03 18:24:42 rubnPC systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, 
code=exited, statu
jun 03 18:24:42 rubnPC systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application 
Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
jun 03 18:24:42 rubnPC systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed 
state.
jun 03 18:24:42 rubnPC systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-
code'.
jun 03 18:24:42 rubnPC polkitd(authority=local)[865]: Unregistered 
Authentication Agent fo
jun 03 18:31:24 rubnPC polkitd(authority=local)[865]: Registered 
Authentication Agent for 
jun 03 18:31:24 rubnPC systemd[1]: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit docker.socket has finished starting up.
```

**System-Info**

```
  rubn _> lsb_release -a
  No LSB modules are available.
  Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
  Description:  Ubuntu 15.10
  Release:  15.10
  Codename: wily
```

**Docker version**

```
rubn _> docker version
Client:
Version:      1.12.6
API version:  1.24
Go version:   go1.6.4
Git commit:   78d1802
Built:        Tue Jan 10 20:32:39 2017
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this 
host?
```

**Kernel Version**

```
rubn _> uname -a 
Linux rubnPC 4.2.0-42-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 21:26:26 UTC 2016 
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**UPDATE: dockerfile**

```
# Set the WILDFLY_VERSION env variable ENV WILDFLY_VERSION 10.0.0.Final ENV WILDFLY_SHA1 c0dd7552c5207b0d116a9c25eb94d10b4f375549
ENV JBOSS_HOME /opt/jboss/wildfly

# Add the WildFly distribution to /opt, and make wildfly the owner of the extracted tar content
# Make sure the distribution is available from a well-known place
RUN cd $HOME \
    && curl -O https://download.jboss.org/wildfly/$WILDFLY_VERSION/wildfly-$WILDFLY_VERSION.tar.gz \
    && sha1sum wildfly-$WILDFLY_VERSION.tar.gz | grep $WILDFLY_SHA1 \
    && tar xf wildfly-$WILDFLY_VERSION.tar.gz \
    && mv $HOME/wildfly-$WILDFLY_VERSION $JBOSS_HOME \
    && rm wildfly-$WILDFLY_VERSION.tar.gz

# Ensure signals are forwarded to the JVM process correctly for graceful shutdown
ENV LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND true

# Expose the ports we're interested in
EXPOSE 8080

# Set the default command to run on boot
# This will boot WildFly in the standalone mode and bind to all interface
CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]

ADD ROOT.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
```

**/etc/default/docker**

```
# Docker Upstart and SysVinit configuration file

#
# THIS FILE DOES NOT APPLY TO SYSTEMD
#
#   Please see the documentation for "systemd drop-ins":
#   https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/systemd/
#

# Customize location of Docker binary (especially for development testing).
#DOCKERD="/usr/local/bin/dockerd"

# Use DOCKER_OPTS to modify the daemon startup options.
#DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4"

# If you need Docker to use an HTTP proxy, it can also be specified here.
#export http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"

# This is also a handy place to tweak where Docker's temporary files go.
#export TMPDIR="/mnt/bigdrive/docker-tmp"
```

**Solved**

[Docker can't connect to docker daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871479/docker-cant-connect-to-docker-daemon)

Comment: [This has nothing to do with software development](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You should be asking on [U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww My interest is to be able to run my dockerfile from intellij

Comment: **Solution**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871479/docker-cant-connect-to-docker-daemon

Comment: @RubénEspinoza Don't put "Solved" in the title of your question. Only forums do that, and Stack Overflow is *not* a forum. Write an answer below detailing how you used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871479/docker-cant-connect-to-docker-daemon in order to solve your case. Then accept your own answer. That will mark your question as "solved", and will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the contents of /etc/default/docker?

It seems you have invalid content that is failing the startup. I'm guessing you have `fd://` in it. If you do, just remove that & then try restarting docker just as before.

Comment: Hi @Anoop , This command had previously executed :s    sudo service docker restart