# How to fix "dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied" when group permissions seem correct?

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04

I'm suddenly having issues after an update of Ubuntu 18.04: previously I've used docker without issue on the system, but suddenly I cannot. As far as I can tell, the permissions look correct:

```
$ docker run hello-world
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.35/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
$ ls -last /var/run/docker.sock 
0 srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Jul 14 09:10 /var/run/docker.sock
$ whoami
brandon
$ cat /etc/group | grep docker
docker:x:995:brandon
nvidia-docker:x:994:
```

**EDIT:**

Group information:

```
$ groups
brandon
$ groups brandon
brandon : brandon adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev games lpadmin sambashare docker
$ whoami
brandon
```

**Update**

I've already rebooted my system to apply the `docker` group. Still with that problem.

Since the original post where I upgraded a system from 17.04 to 18.04, I've done two upgrades from 16.04 to 18.04, and neither of the later systems had the issue. So it might be something to do with the 17.04 to 18.04 upgrade process. I've yet to perform a fresh 18.04 installation.

Comment: Does it work if you run `sudo docker run hello-world`?

Comment: What happens if you run `newgrp docker` and try again from the same terminal?

Comment: @mviereck @BMitch - `sudo` worked, I had tried earlier but with a script wrapping a docker command, so that failed (oops). `newgrp docker` gives me a shell where running the command without `sudo` works. So is something wonky going on with my login shell?

Comment: Following up on the `newgrp` lead, the `groups` output seems a bit suspect.

Comment: Have you tried completely logging off of your Ubuntu session and logging back on again?

Comment: Yes, in fact I rebooted the system.

Comment: Can you try using your secondary TTYs (Ctrl-Alt-F3)?

Comment: In fact, I just confirmed that logging in remotely to the system works: correct `groups` output is shown for the current user. Previously I'd been doing this through XFCE's terminal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker can't connect to docker daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871479/docker-cant-connect-to-docker-daemon)

Comment: @DavidMaze - I don't believe so - the `newgrp` suggestion above worked, as did logging into the system via `ssh`

Comment: @bbarker - with Linux Mint 20.1 (based on Ubuntu 20.04), a reboot was required after "apt install docker.io" and adding myself to the "docker" group. New shell after adding myself to the group would not show me in the docker group via command "id".  "newgrp docker" worked as a workaround until the reboot.

Answer (score 349):

```
sudo setfacl --modify user:<user name or ID>:rw /var/run/docker.sock
```

It doesn't require a restart and is more secure than usermod or chown.

as @mirekphd pointed out, the user ID is required when the user **name** only exists inside the container, but not on the host.

Comment: Thanks. As it happens, I still have this buggy system, though I'm not sure for how many more months! As it happens, this works. Will check to see if it persist on reboot.

Comment: (It doesn't seem to persist through reboots)

Comment: @bbarker https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372244/how-can-i-make-acl-settings-on-run-media-persistent Though on many systems this is persistant

Comment: @Tvde1 https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/92717/is-there-a-raspbian-package-that-installs-setfacl

Comment: setfacl -m jenkins:docker:rw /var/run/docker.sock

setfacl: Option -m: Invalid argument near character 9

Comment: @ShacharHamuzimRajuan you need to run setfacl --modify for a user, e.g: setfacl -m u:docker:rw or u:jenkins:rw . Or per group (g instead of u). see: 
https://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl

Comment: Why would I want to use this over adding the user to the docker group? This seems like a short sighted trial and error fix. If there are other permissions necessary the docker group is probably what it is for. Permissions will be adequate for the docker group, and so users that are to use docker should be part of the docker group. Fixing it for only this user and one socket file may lead to further issues now or later on other files.

Comment: @Kissaki you're right, for robust prod/staging envs you'd want to carefully manage a group rather than a user and a file. This is obviously a dev/test issue where people just want to get on with things, with some user that needs temporary, immediate access. Access control lists are meant to be more precise and secure than groups; in this case this just skips the reboot that usemod requires. It's also more secure than chown, I've seen some clusters crashing with that sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock trick that somebody posted below

Comment: The `Invalid argument near character` error is caused by missing user name (e.g. you used `jenkins` on the host, but such user exists only inside a docker container). To avoid the problem, just use UID instead of user name.

Comment: So basically `sudo setfacl --modify user:$(whoami):rw /var/run/docker.sock` ... why not name it?

Comment: @0xC0000022L as mirekphd mentioned sometimes it's gotta be the user ID

Comment: @DanielRch. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372244/how-can-i-make-acl-settings-on-run-media-persistent Though on many systems this is persistant

Comment: The chosen correct answer here is more complete for prod ready images: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53126950/permission-denied-to-docker-daemon-socket-at-unix-var-run-docker-sock?rq=1

Answer (score 132):

add the user to the docker group.

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but the output of 'groups brandon' already includes 'docker', in my case, as indicated above. But this is generally good advice.

Comment: Reboot helps :)

Comment: Creating a new user session (logging out and back in) is enough to update the user sessions groups. No reboot required.

Comment: Instead of rebooting, you can just restart the docker daemon *sudo systemctl restart docker*

Comment: restarting the docker daemon and logging out/in weren't sufficient for me. A reboot was.

Comment: If on WSL, close out, and run from powershell `wsl --shutdown` to full close out of WSL.

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04, a reboot was necessary for me too. Logging out and in was not sufficient.

Comment: I don't understand why this is not the most upvoted option? The most upvoted is a non-persistant option that doesn't match the right nature of doing things well with docker.

Answer (score 109):

Just try to give the right permission to docker.sock file by:

```
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: this worked for me on Win10 WSL 2 and Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: magically this worked for me on Ubuntu Server

Comment: this worked on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: Note that this allows any user on your system to control Docker. If you have a mulit-user system, it's probably not what you want.

Comment: This is very insecure. It could potentially allow someone to take control of the underlying Docker host if user namespaces are not used.

Comment: @PaulCalabro That's why it's 666 bro.  Cause it's dangerous and insecure!  Ha ha ha

Comment: Don't do this. This is a security risk as already said. Instead, assign a custom group to that sock file (example: "docker"), and be in that group (sudo adduser YOURUSER docker) and eventually reboot.

Answer (score 37):

The way to fix it is to run:

```sh
sudo addgroup --system docker
sudo adduser $USER docker
newgrp docker
```

that works for me :)

Comment: newgrp docker was the step missing from the guide I was following in my case

Answer (score 21):

Ubuntu 18:04

```
sudo setfacl --modify user:$USER:rw /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: What does that do?

Answer (score 10):

It looks like a permission issue:

```bash
sudo addgroup --system docker
sudo adduser $USER docker
newgrp docker
sudo setfacl -m "g:docker:rw" /var/run/docker.sock
```

or Simply use this command below, which will fix this issue.

```bash
sudo chmod -x /var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score 7):

Somehow, i found this page when i have't correct permissons on my docker.sock after my Docker installation. So, if you have the same issue, you can read this:

> $ sudo adduser $USER docker does not work because the group is "root"
> not "docker"
>
> $ ls -l /var/run/docker.sock srw-rw---- 1 root root 0 Jul 11 09:48
> /var/run/docker.sock so it should be $ sudo adduser $USER root
>
> from a non-snap installed machine, the group is "docker"
>
> # ls -l /var/run/docker.sock srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Jul  3 04:18 /var/run/docker.sock The correct way is, according to docker.help you
> have to run the followings BEFORE sudo snap install docker
>
> $ sudo addgroup --system docker $ sudo adduser $USER docker $ newgrp
> docker then the group will be "docker"
>
> $ ls -l /var/run/docker.sock srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Jul 11 10:59
> /var/run/docker.sock

Source: https://github.com/docker-archive/docker-snap/issues/1 (yes, first issue :D)

The easyest way to fix it is to run:

```
$ sudo setfacl -m "g:docker:rw" /var/run/docker.sock
```

And then, as it already metioned, run following commands for your user:

```
$sudo addgroup --system docker
$sudo adduser $USER docker
$newgrp docker
```

That's it :) Have fun!

Answer (score 6):

I did the quick fix and it worked immediately.

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: That may look like an easy solution in case you're just playing around with Docker on a dev environment, but that's a very bad idea for the security of your system.

Comment: sudo setfacl -m user:brandon:rw /var/run/docker.sock
gives just the one user the permissions it needs.

Comment: when suggesting something that is insecure please write a warning

Comment: Don't do this. This is a security risk as already said. Instead, assign a custom group to that sock file (example: "docker"), and be in that group (sudo adduser YOURUSER docker) and eventually reboot.

Answer (score 4):

**For ubuntu 20.04**

Step1 : Check Ubuntu **user**

```
echo $USER
```

Step2 : give **rw** permission to docker

```
sudo setfacl --modify user:<user_name>:rw /var/run/docker.sock
```

**Example**

**Getting error**

[image]

**Solution**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Specific to Ubuntu, there is a known issue with lightdm that removes secondary groups from the user as part of the GUI login. You can follow that issue here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/1781418

You can try switching off of lightdm or apply the workaround mentioned in the bug report:

> [Comment out the below lines from /etc/pam.d/lightdm:]
>
> ```
> auth optional pam_kwallet.so
> auth optional pam_kwallet5.so
> ```

Temporary options include logging into your machine with something like an ssh or `su -l` command, or running the `newgrp docker` command. These will only affect the current shell and would need to be done again with each new terminal.

---

Outside of this issue, the general commands to give a user direct access to the docker socket (and therefore root access to the host) are:

```bash
sudo usermod -aG docker $(id -un) # you can often use $USER in place of the id command
newgrp docker # affects the current shell, logging out should affect all shells
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this on my Linux Machine using the below command.

```
> sudo setfacl --modify user:$USER:rw /var/run/docker.sock
```

Note: Please checck if you have sudo access. Otherwise this command will fail.

How to check sudo access?

```
$ whoami
> rahul
$ groups
> useracc
$ groups useracc
> Here you can see sudo and other access details.
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by using the following command:

```sh
sudo chmod -x /var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note: **not only group name is important**, but apparently also gid of the groups.
So if *docker* group on host system has gid of i.e. 995,

```
cat /etc/group | grep docker  
docker:x:995:brandon
```

You must make sure gid of docker *group*
You can do this as a part of a launch script, or simply by using *exec* and doing it manually:

```
groupmod -g 995 docker
```

Hope it helps anyone who comes here, it took me a while to find this answear.

Answer (score 0):

**This issue is resolved by following the process below**

1. Check whether the "**docker**" group is created or not

   cmd: `cat /etc/group | grep docker`

   output: `docker:x:995`
2. Check the permissions of "**/var/run/docker.sock**" file

   *cmd:* `ls -l /var/run/docker.sock`

   *output:* `rw-rw---- 1 root root 0 Jul 14 09:10 /var/run/docker.sock`
3. add docker group to "**/var/run/docker.sock**" file

*cmd:* `sudo setfacl -m "g:docker:rw" /var/run/docker.sock`

*output:* `rw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Jul 14 09:10 /var/run/docker.sock`

4. Now it will work, if possible restart the docker service.
5. To restart the docker service

   *cmd:* `sudo systemctl restart docker`

Answer (score 0):

All of above solutions are working, but are not persistent after system reboot, which was most important for me. I was seraching for persistent solution and only thing what works for me is to change SocketMode to 0666 in file
'/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket'

```
...
SocketMode=0666
...
```

after changing this file we need to restart the service

> sudo systemctl daemon-reload
> sudo systemctl restart docker.socket

Now the permission will be properly set by service itself after service restart.

Comment: Don't do this. This is a security risk as already said. Instead, assign a custom group to that sock file (example: "docker"), and be in that group (sudo adduser YOURUSER docker) and eventually reboot.

Comment: tried this for testing and it didn't help with my issue. It should have no issues when looking at permissions....