# I don't have permission to access Docker and every new terminal instance I need to run newgrp docker

Tags: docker

I installed Docker as per suggestion on the official website. I ran into problems regarding permissions of the .sock file.

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.8
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        afacb8b7f0
 Built:             Wed Mar 11 01:25:55 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/version: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

I already created and recreated the `docker` group as well as my user to the group and logged out many times, all to continue resulting in the above error. The only thing that "solves" is running `newgrp docker`, but it then only works for that instance of the terminal.

How do I prevent this? I don't want to add that command to my `.zshrc`. It has always worked just by adding my user to the `docker` user.

**Edit**

I noticed that when running `groups`, `docker` is not there despite the thousands attempts to add my user to it. Why?

Comment: Humm that's weird... Can you check in your `/etc/group` file that your user is really in the docker group ?

Comment: Ok, just saw the edit, can you post the command you used to add your user to the `docker` group then ?

Comment: It shows `docker:x:1001:` only; and the commands I tried were these: `sudo usermod -aG docker gabriel`, `sudo usermod -a -G docker gabriel` and `sudo usermod -G docker -a 'gabriel'`, Three, and none worked. I don't know why it began to be like this. It used to be so simple.

Comment: And (just to be sure) when you do `echo $USER` it prints `gabriel` right ?

Comment: Yes it does print gabriel

Comment: Hey, I solved it with this command: `sudo setfacl -m user:gabriel:rw /var/run/docker.sock`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permission denied to Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53126950/permission-denied-to-docker-daemon-socket-at-unix-var-run-docker-sock)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved it with this command: `sudo setfacl -m user:$USER:rw /var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: This works for me. A more general command would be:

sudo setfacl -m user:$USER:rw /var/run/docker.sock