# How to log docker healthcheck status in docker logs?

Tags: docker, logging, dockerfile

**Objective**

I want to check if my docker container is healthy or not by verifying the docker logs.

**Requirements**

I have **two files** namely `Dockerfile` and `loop.sh` and I have added a HEALTHCHECK to my docker as follows:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine
ADD . /
HEALTHCHECK --interval=1s --timeout=30s --retries=3 CMD echo {'health':'healthy'}
CMD ["sh","loop.sh"]
```

**loop.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

while 1>0;do echo "1"; sleep 2; done;
```

**Observation**

- Observation 1

The `docker logs` just outputs the `integer 1` as mentioned in the `loop.sh` but do not outputs the health status of my docker. An image is attached below-
[image: Output of docker logs]

- Observation 2

The `docker ps` command shows that the container is healthy and hence deducing that my healthcheck is working. Please find the attached image below-

[image: Output of Docker ps command]

- Observation 3

The `docker inspect` command also shows the health status of the docker container. Please find the screenshot below-
[image: Health status]

**Problem**

How to log this `{'health':'healthy'}` healthcheck status so that it can be seen in the docker logs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, this is super hacky and I'm not proud of it. The issue is that the healthcheck runs in a different process than your main process, so it's hard to write to the main process' `stdout`.

But you can exploit that the main process (usually) runs as process #1 and write to `/proc/1/fd/1` which is that process' `stdout`. Something like this

```
FROM ubuntu
HEALTHCHECK --interval=1s --timeout=30s --retries=3 CMD echo {'health': 'healthy'} | tee /proc/1/fd/1
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

The `tail -f /dev/null` is just a dummy command that keeps the container running.

Comment: Thank you so much, Hans, though it is hacky it has saved me from a lot of trouble. You should definitely be proud of it. Thank you for your amazing response.

Comment: Just out of curiosity- Docker inspect gives a more accurate status of the health within its JSON structure (Health.status = healthy), would you know if there is a file where docker stores this status, and you can simply retrieve it and throw it on proc/1/fd/1?

Comment: I don't think so. The detailed health status is only known to Docker which means that it's held outside the container. I don't know of a way you could get hold of it from inside the container and put it into the logs.

Comment: @HansKilian You may run docker commands from within a docker container but you need to give it the access to the `/var/run/docker.sock` socket. See answers for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53126950/permission-denied-to-docker-daemon-socket-at-unix-var-run-docker-sock)