# Is there a way to send a message in docker's logs stream from healthcheck.sh

Tags: docker, logging, health-check

I built a docker image like that:
Dockerfile:

```
FROM busybox
WORKDIR /
COPY healthcheck.sh .
RUN chmod +x healthcheck.sh
HEALTHCHECK --start-period=1s --interval=2s --timeout=3s --retries=3 CMD /healthcheck.sh || exit 1
CMD while true; do $(echo date); sleep 10; done
```

helthcheck.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $HOSTNAME ]; then
  echo "OK"
  exit 0
else
  echo "FAIL"
  exit 1
fi
```

My goal is to send an "OK" or "FAIL" in the container's log stream along with a date.

Is there a way to achieve that? "log-driver": "awslogs"

Thanks!

Comment: Which docker logging driver are you using? Usually any text printed to stdout should go to the logs

Comment: I am planning to use awslogs. now I am testing on a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 and newly installed docker via `curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com | bash`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [AWS cloud watch log driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/awslogs/#amazon-cloudwatch-logs-options)
With this configuration, anything sent stdout will be shipped to AWS.

> The issue is that the healthcheck runs in a different process than your main process, so it's hard to write to the main process' stdout.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68929795/1563297) there is a hacky solution to circumvent this

Comment: well, the problem is that it does not behave like that neither with `awslogs` nor default `json-file` driver. Test it. I provided the files.

Comment: I can see dates in logs but there is no "OK" no "FAIL"

Comment: Ah, got it. I updated the answer.