# Permission issue on running docker command in Python subprocess through Apache Airflow

Tags: docker, airflow

Any idea why I can't run docker using Airflow?

The same docker command runs fine from terminal using the user that runs airflow. **So there is no permission issue on the Linux side.**

But when put it into Airflow dag, it complains

> docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker
>   daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post
>   http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/create: dial unix
>   /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.

The command is simply `docker run --rm -v /data:/data:ro docker_image mycommand`. It is wrapped inside a python subprocess, so I can't use docker operator.

Note this is not the same issue with the question: [How to fix "dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied" when group permissions seem correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342810/how-to-fix-dial-unix-var-run-docker-sock-connect-permission-denied-when-gro)
There it is a linux permission issue as it cannot run the `docker run` command. Here the problem is more with Airflow, I think.

Comment: Can you add the code snippet for this and also for the successful condition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied" when group permissions seem correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342810/how-to-fix-dial-unix-var-run-docker-sock-connect-permission-denied-when-gro)

Comment: @mchawre The mentioned question is a linux permission problem. The issue I have is with Apache Airflow.

Comment: The user that Airflow is running as doesn't have permission to access `/var/run/docker.sock`. There are several ways of working around this, but I'd recommend Impersonating a more privileged user using `run_as_user` on the Airflow action that runs docker:  https://airflow.apache.org/security.html#impersonation

Comment: @ArtGillespie The user that Airflow is running has the privilege to run docker command. There is no permission issue on Linux side.

Comment: This worked for me and its clean too, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57724705/windows-docker-permission-denied-var-run-docker-sock?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faced a similar issue . 
Got it fixed by changing the default_owner(default=airflow) in airflow.cfg to the user having permission to access docker(i.e username belonging to docker group).

Interestingly passing owner in 'default_args' in the DAG definition didn't seem to work

Comment: A very interesting answer :) Waiting for someone to validate this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the reason is in access rights to /var/run/docker.sock.
For dev environment, you can do:

```
docker exec -ti -u root <container> bash
sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock
```