# Windows docker: permission denied /var/run/docker.sock

Tags: windows, docker, filebeat

When I try to run filebeat with autodiscover I get the following error:

> Exiting: error in autodiscover provider settings: Got permission
>   denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at
>   unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get
>   http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.22/containers/json?limit=0: dial
>   unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

I exposed the daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 from docker settings.

I checked that my user is member of "docker-users" group.

docker-compose.yml:

```
filebeat:
    image: store/elastic/filebeat:7.3.0
    volumes:
      - ./config/filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml:ro
      - /var/lib/docker/containers/:/var/lib/docker/containers/:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding `user: root` to docker-compose.yml fixes socket access:

```
filebeat:
    image: store/elastic/filebeat:7.3.0
    volumes:
      - ./config/filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml:ro
      - /var/lib/docker/containers/:/var/lib/docker/containers/:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    user: root
```

Comment: This also fixed Jenkins access to the Docker UNIX socket (on Windows Docker-Desktop)

Comment: This also fixed TeamCity access to the Docker socket (on Windows Docker Desktop)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the first answer which shows up when searching for this exact error message, under Windows, here is the answer to solve it with an oldschool `Dockerfile`, when running it from the command-line:

```
docker run -u root -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker_in_docker docker run hello-world
```

Pay attention to the added `-u root`, which solved it for me.

(`docker_in_docker` is the name of the Docker image.)

Comment: Where is the dockerfile?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson The place of the Dockerfile is irrelevant after the image creation. The Dockerfile is just the standard installation of Docker, but without a running daemon.

Comment: If the dockerfile is not important to your answer, then please don't call it out explicitly in your answer, implying that it is important.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson But the `Dockerfile` is important. There are 2 modes of image construction (regardless of file location or content): One is via `Dockerfile` the other is via Docker-Compose.

Comment: Can you please elaborate then? It seems to be that the important part of your answer is changing permissions for running the `docker run` command, and not the specific image or Dockerfile.