# Permission denied on Docker daemon socket in TeamCity Agent

Tags: windows, docker, continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm a newbie to CI and TeamCity.
I have run TeamCity server and agent with Docker, using docker-compose.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  server:
    image: jetbrains/teamcity-server:latest
    ports:
      - "8111:8111"
    volumes:
      - C:\TeamCity\server\data:/data/teamcity_server/datadir
      - C:\TeamCity\server\logs:/opt/teamcity/logs
  agent:
    image: jetbrains/teamcity-agent:latest
    environment:
      - SERVER_URL=http://server:8111
    volumes:
      - C:\TeamCity\agent\conf:/data/teamcity_agent/conf
      - C:\TeamCity\agent\logs:/opt/buildagent/logs
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

I have set the TeamCity server to do some build steps, including a build step that pushes a Docker image on an Azure Container Registry. 
When the pipeline starts the agent tries to connect to the registry (the connection is working server side) but I get this error:

```
Cannot login to registry xxx.azurecr.io
An error occurred while executing 'docker login -u "TeamCity" --password-stdin xxx.azurecr.io':
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/auth": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

Reading on the web, including similar SO questions to mine, I found that the problem seems to be that the agent is not in the `docker` group.

I'm running on Windows and all the answers, including the official guide of TeamCity, do examples on Linux. Anyway, I tried my best.

I entered the agent docker with `docker exec -it teamcity-agent-1 /bin/bash` and seems to be already in the `docker` group. `cat etc/group` --> `docker:x:999:buildagent`
Here is the SO question with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854463/docker-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socke).

I also tried to add `teamcity.docker.use.sudo=true` in the configuration file of the agent as the [official guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/docker.html#Running+Docker+via+sudo) suggests, but then the server does not recognize the agent as a suitable agent with Docker installed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem adding `user: root` in my `docker-compose.yaml` as suggested in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57724705/windows-docker-permission-denied-var-run-docker-sock?rq=2)