# Running hello-world Docker on Libreelec/Kodi on Raspberry Pi causes response from daemon error

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, kodi

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://cwilko.github.io/home%20automation/2017/02/28/Raspberry-Pi-Home-Server.html) to install Docker on my Librelect/Kodi Raspberry pi box. I have followed all the steps but when I run:

```
docker -H 0.0.0.0:2375 run hello-world
```

I get the error message:

> Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
>
> docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp:lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.1.1:53: read udp 192.168.1.55:40093->192.168.1.1:53: i/o timeout.
>
> See 'docker run --help'.

I have seen other posts with similar problems but all are on decent operating systems with proper Unix tools like `service` and proper package managers. For example almost all of the commands suggested on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871479/docker-cant-connect-to-docker-daemon) lead to `-sh: <command> not found` errors. On Libreelec the only package manager I have found so far is Entware, which is a hassle to get around. I would appreciate if you could Help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it.

**P.S.1.** When I run `docker version` I get the message:

> Client:
>   Version:      1.13.1
>   API version:  1.26
>   Go version:  go1.7.5
>   Git commit:   1.13.1
>   Built:        Sat Jul 15 18:44:26 UTC
>   2017  OS/Arch:      linux/arm 
>   Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

**P.S.2** It has been mentioned in [some posts](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1317) that changing DNS server to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` on Docker settings solves the problem. But I don't know how to do this.

Comment: That sounds like your host's DNS setup isn't working.

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm very novice on this matter. Would you please elaborate?