# Building Docker container in Google Colab: unknown flag -t

Tags: bash, docker, installation, google-colaboratory

I am trying to bring a github repo into my Google Colab workspace via the following code:

```
!git clone https://github.com/vanvalenlab/deepcell-tf.git
!cd deepcell-tf
!docker build -t $USER/deepcell-tf .
```

I have followed Google Colab's steps for install Docker (https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10OinT5ZNGtdLLQ9K399jlKgNgidxUbGP).

But when I run the above code, I get the following error:

```
invalid argument "/deepcell-tf" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format
See 'docker build --help'.
```

"-t" is a valid argument to pass according to the documentation. Why does it think I'm passing /deepcell-tf as an argument?

Comment: Looks like the `$USER` variable is not set. Can you make sure that it has a value? (`echo $USER`)

Comment: Oh you're right, `!echo $USER` returns nothing. Should I change `$USER/deepcell-tf` to deepcell-tf's path?

Comment: It is up to you. It depends on how you want your docker image name/tag built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`-t`](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options) is indeed a valid flag:

> `--tag` , `-t`        Name and optionally a tag in the `name:tag` format

The problem is that your `$USER` variable is not set, and your command is being interpreted as `docker build -t /deepcell-tf .`, which is an invalid form for naming the image.

You need to make sure to export the `$USER` value before running the `docker build`, or setting it manually to a valid value. E.g.:

```
docker build -t my-user/deepcell-tf .
```

Comment: That definitely makes sense. After reading this, I tried `!docker build -t content/deepcell-tf .`    and I get the error: `ERRO[0000] failed to dial gRPC: cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker daemon' running on this host?: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: connection refused 
error during connect:`

I had started the Docker by running `!/etc/init.d/docker start`, so I'm not sure how this could happen

Comment: This error generally means that your docker daemon is not running, or that your user doesn't have proper permissions. You can retry it appending `sudo` to your command or by [adding your user to `docker` group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38157703/7641078) (you will need to restart after this).

Answer (score 0):

The notebook you linked isn't actually published by Google, it was just made by another user.

Google Colab doesn't support Docker, and they currently have no plans to support it, unfortunately: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/299