# How do I install and configure Docker on Ubuntu-like systems (Kubuntu)

Tags: linux, docker, ddev

i tried using ddev with Linux Kubuntu and did as proceeded as described here:

https://t3terminal.com/typo3-tutorials/install-typo3-docker-ddev/

means:

```
// Install DDEV
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drud/ddev/master/scripts/install_ddev.sh | bash

// Install mkcert
sudo apt install libnss3-tools
mkcert -install

// Check DDEV works well?
ddev
```

```
$ ddev config
… Project name (temp-test): test
… Docroot Location (current directory): 
Found a php codebase at ~/github/temp-test. 
… Project Type [backdrop, drupal6, drupal7, drupal8, drupal9, laravel, magento, magento2, php, shopware6, typo3, wordpress] (php): laravel
… You may now run 'ddev start'. 

~/github/temp-test$ ddev start
Could not connect to docker. Please ensure Docker is installed and running.
```

So i found this tip's here: [Docker can't connect to docker daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55022110/2891692) :

```
~/github/temp-test$ sudo service docker stop && sudo service docker start
Warning: Stopping docker.service, but it can still be activated by:
  docker.socket
~/github/temp-test$ ddev start
Could not connect to docker. Please ensure Docker is installed and running.
~/github/temp-test$ sudo service docker start
~/github/temp-test$ ddev start
Could not connect to docker. Please ensure Docker is installed and running.
~/github/temp-test$ sudo service docker restart
~/github/temp-test$
```

it looks as if docker is installed (because it talks to me `Warning: Stopping docker.service`) but ddev does not find docker. what else can try?

## Docker version

```
~ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d
```

## Operating System

Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8

Answer (score 0):

You need to install docker on Kubuntu to use it.

Details are in the [ddev docs].(https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/docker_installation/#linux-installation-docker-and-docker-compose)

But the bottom line is:

- You're using the Ubuntu setup.
- Use the instructions for Ubuntu 20.04 assuming you're using something 20.04+: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install docker.io docker-compose`
- Make sure to do the post-install, which requires you to add your own user to the "docker" group. `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`, details in the [linked docker instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/)

Comment: but its already installed. see this line `Stopping docker.service, but it can still be activated`

Comment: `~ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d`

Comment: It sure looks like you failed to add your user to the docker group. `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER` - if `sudo docker ps` works but `docker ps` doesn't, that's exactly what's going on. Note that you probably have to log out and log in again to get the user added properly.

Comment: `docker ps` works. it returns `CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES` nothing more (no other rows)

Comment: If `docker ps` works, docker is working. You shouldn't get any complaints from ddev about docker not being there. Try your `ddev start` again.