# Could not connect to a docker provider. Please start or install a docker provider

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, sudo, ddev

I am installing **Drupal** on Linux(Ubuntu 20.04) using ddev. **ddev** requires docker installed and in Ubuntu, I can connect with docker using sudo. If I want to check for the running container I will use the command.

```
sudo docker ps
```

But when I run this command to configure the local environment using ddev. I got this error. The error tells that ddev unable to connect with docker provider.

```
ddev config --docroot web --project-name my-site --project-type drupal10 --create-docroot
```

This error is given.

**Could not connect to a docker provider. Please start or install a docker provider.**

The solution to this issue is that I need to make the docker run without sudo. I have browsed this issue and found different solutions and tried them but none of them is working. These are the coammands I tried to solve the issue.

I tried to run the ddev command using sudo this got this error.

```
sudo ddev config --docroot web --project-name my-site --project-type drupal10 --create-docroot
```

**WARN[0000] not reading global config file because running with root privileges
Not populating custom commands or hostadditions because running with root privileges
ddev is not designed to be run with root privileges, please run as normal user and without sudo**

```
sudo groupadd docker

sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)

sudo service docker start
```

But this has not solved the issue. I have followed this link for the solution but that also has not worked.
[Docker can't connect to docker daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871479/docker-cant-connect-to-docker-daemon)

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: You need to log out and back in for group membership to be effective.  Check with `groups` and make sure that `docker` appears in the list of your assigned groups.

Comment: restarting the system solved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

The normal reason for this is that you haven't done the post-install activities required for docker. If `sudo docker ps` works, but `docker ps` fails, that's what's going on.

As it says in the [DDEV docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/install/docker-installation/#linux) don't forget the [post-installation steps for linux](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/).

Normally all you have to do is `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER` and then reboot.

@grobu gave you the answer in a comment.

There are also situations where you are using the wrong docker context. You may want to use `docker context ls` to see what contexts are available and which one you are set to. Use `docker context <contextname>` to switch to the right one.

Comment: Thank you very much. Rebooting solved the issue.