# Running Program on Linux Server Over Putty?

Tags: linux, putty

I recently just set up a program on a Linux Server over Putty.  I want this program to be running at all times and was wondering how I could do this without having to keep my own computer on at all times (because if I close Putty, the program is also killed).  Would I need console access to the server?  Sorry, kind of new to this :(

Comment: Us [tmux screen](http://www.dayid.org/os/notes/tm.html) it's way cooler :D and you better ask such questions on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GNU Screen

- $ screen -R MY-SESSION-NAME
- $ ./YOUR-PROGRAM
- `CTRL-A` (release keys) `D` to detach

You can reattach with `screen -ddR` and list screen sessions with `screen -ls`. Read a tutorial like http://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/ for more details

Comment: Thanks!  That seemed to work just perfectly!  Such a simple question that I really should know :P

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the application in the background using nohup. So if your application is called myappp and is located in the current directory execute

nohup ./myapp &

Answer (score 0):

It seems your scenario is you´re running a program on a Linux box program througth putty from a Windows machine. And yuo want keep the program running even after closing the conection. Well for accomplish that you have tio ensure the program don´t close with your session, in other words it has to be independant. So, you need create a service (see: [Making a script into a linux service](https://serverfault.com/questions/100485/making-a-script-into-a-linux-service)) or [run the script at linux startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup).

You can then use putty just for configuring how the program starts. And not for start the program.