# Previous installation of Tomcat complains of missing file - Beginner

Tags: linux, unix, tomcat, centos

I deleted few Tomcat installations from the Linux server (CentOS). There after i installed Tomcat 8. Now when i try to start Tomcat 8 (`./startup.sh`) it gives the following error:

```
Cannot find /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.56/bin/setclasspath.sh
This file is needed to run this program
```

Seems like i have not removed the previous installation of tomcat properly. How can i get this to work. Help.

Update

```
[root@localhost bin]# ./startup.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

Comment: I think the launcher you using `./startup.sh` is of Tomcat 7 and new launcher should be there.

Comment: No i deleted all that was there in that folder ? Do you think that it has to be something with setting paths ?

Comment: Yes it could be problem with JRE settings

Comment: How can i remove it. Every time i type a command related to tomcat it gives me the above error. Even `./version`.

Comment: yeah until the path is configured the system will not able to recognized the utility or command you asking for.

Comment: I typed `unset CATALINA_HOME` and then started the script and then it works. Can you check my updated Post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to run this command

```
unset CATALINA_HOME
```

This command will unset the environmental variable CATALINA_HOME.

There is two ways to add this command to start up linux command as follows

[First method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup)

[Second method](https://superuser.com/questions/685471/how-can-i-run-a-command-after-boot)

Now you will not have to run this command again and again on booting.

Comment: Yes. i tried that. then it worked. However, every time i restart the server i have to type the above code. Is there a permanent solution for this ?

Comment: I have pasted the output i got. Is there any problem with the JRE

Comment: no as I said it may be have problems but as of I seen the output I don't think there is any problem with JRE.

Comment: I have added two methods to run the command in start up use any one of them I hope that will be fine to run automatically on boot

Comment: @Emdadul it's a pleasure to help you