# Running a python script continuously, from system startup

Tags: python, linux, windows, python-2.7

Is it possible to run a python script continuously from system startup, preferably in windows( i might also need the linux version). It is to continuously ping my remote server and check for updates and notify the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to implement a service.
Take a look at the following: [Is it possible to run a python script as a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/is-it-possible-to-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows-if-possible-how)

Comment: Thank you sir!, but what about on linux? also, Please do mention if you know a simpler solution, as the code mentioned was a bit complex.

Comment: For linux it might depend on your distribution. But a small can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup And maybe a more simple approach for Windows will be the startup folder of the user. But that will only work when you login automatically. Or you are ok with logging in before the script is started.