# Start shell script on Raspberry Pi startup

Tags: python, shell, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a python program which posts to my local web server. The script runs on a raspberry pi running the latest version of raspbian 3.18. How can I make the Python script run at startup? Raspbian has a login password which is the first thing I have to remove. If the power ever goes out I want the pi to reboot and start running my script again. Should I be using Raspbian for this? The script is the only thing the pi is used for. I tried adding the script to /etc/init.d but I do not think it will run either way if the pi requires login info upon booting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12973826/3745735

Comment: Thanks but im not sure if that will run the program without having to login. Can someone confirm this?

Comment: Zudo's link will work without the need of login in

Comment: I tried all the steps in the link above and it still did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the program is executable

```
chmod +x filename.py
```

open /etc/rc.local in your editor of choice

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

and add

```
python /FULL PATH TO SCRITP/filename.py
```

before the exit

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Linux crontab to run the Python script. Let's go to root and create a shell script.

`sudo -i`

`nano startup.sh`

Then type your python script on this bash script. navigate to home directory, then to this directory, then execute python script, then back home.

`cd /
cd home/pi/your directory
sudo python yourpythonscript.py
cd /`

Save the script and then exit. Make this sh script executable by giving it permission.

`chmod 755 startup.sh`

Now open and edit rc.local file.

`nano /etc/rc.local`

Add `/root/startup.sh &` before exit 0

now save and exit from the file and reboot your pi.

`sudo reboot`