# How to startup my python script automatically in ubuntu

Tags: python, linux

***I need my own gnome applet python program to run automatically when system starts.***

Comment: Check out http://www.pygtk.org/articles/applets_arturogf/ it contains some pretty decent information for setting things up

Comment: please read how to ask question here.

Comment: Your answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is put a script in `/etc/init.d/` and it will run on startup.

Also, be sure to put the interpreter at the top of the file, such as `#! /bin/bash`, and be sure to make it executable with `chmod +x /etc/init.d/myscript`

**Example file**

```
#! /bin/bash
python /path/to/my/script.py
```

Comment: I am getting this error in syslog how to fix it "GtkWarning: IA__gdk_screen_get_root_window: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed".

Comment: @Ajay It's probably something to do with your script. It sounds like something to do with a GUI, and if you're trying to run an application with a GUI on startup, you would want to have it run when you login, rather than on boot.