# Start PHP command line on boot

Tags: php, linux, boot

I am running a script that has to run at the user level, I do not want to change the PHP daemon to run as another user.

Currently I have to manually type 
    php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 /home/user

This works if I input it manually but I want to be able to do this when it boots up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a script containing your command.

it can be a one-liner such as `#!/usr/bin/php -S 127.0.0.1:8081 /home/knb` 
(does NOT work for me)

Make the script executable with `chmod ugo+x myscript.php`

In Ubuntu, there is a GUI tool called "Startup Applications" where you have to enter the full pathname of your script in the textfield labeled "Command:".

ALternatively, If you want to use systemd for this (e.g., to execute the script at bootup for all users, no matter who logs in), read this : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47695/how-to-write-startup-script-for-systemd and follow the instructions (copy  + paste an existing minimal startscript, customize it)

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna run php script then create a bash command.
[How to run shell script at boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup)
theres a topic that might help you in this case :)