# Launch a Node.Js server when the operating system starts

Tags: node.js

I have a website written in Node.Js that I launch with this command :

```
cd /var/mywebsite
npm run dev
```

What should I put in /etc/init.d/rc.local ?

A solution is : https://causeyourestuck.io/2016/04/30/run-node-js-script-startup/
But I don't know how to create the app.js...

Thanks !

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could use continues integration tools such as puppet to help you do accomplish this. You can also integrate it with Jenkins for the full lifecycle.

https://forge.puppet.com/puppet/nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are on Linux Ubuntu I think the best and most simple option is a CronTab

```
#crontab -e
@reboot  /home/user/startServer.sh
```

then your shell/bash script should look something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
node server.js
```

or

```
#!/user/bin/bash
npm run dev
```

Let me know if that helps, or if you run into issues. I haven't used linux in a few months :)

more info: [How to run a shell script at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup)

Comment: I have made the script, made it executable, added it to crontab (as ubuntu user, not root), and it doesn't work...

This is the script :

    #!/bin/bash
    cd /var/www/mywebsite
    npm run dev

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a process manager like `pm2`.

```
npm i -g pm2
#install pm2

pm2 start <in your project directory>
#starts the project (can start multiple)

pm2 startup
#setup init scripts to start processes on reboot

pm2 save
#saves list of processes
```

Ref: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/

Comment: Thanks.
"pm2 start" gives me :
error: missing required argument `file|json|stdin|app_name|pm_id'

What should I put ? I don't have any app.js file

Comment: It tries to run the `start` script from package.json. You can use `pm2 start somefile.js` if your package.json is not setup that way.

Comment: OK, I understand now the problem.
My package.json looks like this (I have no .js file mentioned) :

  "name": "myapp",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon -w ./server --exec \"babel-node server --presets es2015,stage-0\"",
    "adduser": "nodemon -w ./server/adduser --exec \"babel-node server/adduser --presets es2015,stage-0\"",
    "build": "babel server -s -D -d dist --presets es2015,stage-0",
    "start": "node dist",
    "prestart": "npm run -s build",
    "test": "eslint src"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.9.4"
  },

Comment: You need to run `npm run build`. This will generate your js files in `dist` directory. Then you can run `pm2 start dist/index.js`.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot for your help. rpm run build works and I have the dist directory. pm2 start dist/index.js works, but pm2 status gives me this status for the app : errored. I thinks that the problem is that when I start the server with "npm run dev" it starts this script (in package.json) : nodemon -w ./server --exec \"babel-node server --presets es2015,stage-0\"

Comment: There are syntax errors in the script because it is not launched the correct way. Part of the log :  /var/www/website/settings.js:8
2|index    | export default {
2|index    | ^^^^^^
2|index    | SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Comment: That's not possible. Run `pm2 flush` then `pm2 delete all` and `pm2 start dist/index.js`

Comment: Just tried, but same problem. Log says :
App [index] with id [0] and pid [7426], exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT] ************ Script /var/www/mywebsite/dist/index.js had too many unstable restarts (16). Stopped. "errored" *********** /var/www/website/settings.js:8 2|index | export default { 2|index | ^^^^^^ 2|index | SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Comment: I think the problem is that is it launched with nodemon (as written in the package.log)

Comment: No, all that is completely unrelated. `npm run build` should produce perfectly working code if everything else is configured properly. But it looks like code inside `dist` is trying to access the non transpiled `settings.js` outside the `dist` directory.

Comment: If your `settings.js` is not too complicated you can convert it to normal syntax, otherwise you'll have configure babel to transpile that as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use forever-service module, you can use it like this:

Install forever & forever-service packages globally:

```
sudo npm install -g forever forever-service
```

Then register your app as a service (default to *app.js*, but you can specify the name of your app if you need to):

```
sudo forever-service install your_app --script the_name_of_your_app --start
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I don't know the name of my app...
I have a server/index.js 
All I know is that I launch my app with npm run dev

Comment: So, probably index.js. Check the script dev line in your _package.json_ to be sure.

Comment: OK, I understand now the problem.
My package.json looks like this (I have no .js file mentioned) :

  "name": "myapp",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon -w ./server --exec \"babel-node server --presets es2015,stage-0\"",
    "adduser": "nodemon -w ./server/adduser --exec \"babel-node server/adduser --presets es2015,stage-0\"",
    "build": "babel server -s -D -d dist --presets es2015,stage-0",
    "start": "node dist",
    "prestart": "npm run -s build",
    "test": "eslint src"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.9.4"
  },

Comment: Give it a try with ./server, otherwise ./server/index.js. And I think you'll need to pass others command line parameters with --scriptOptions argument. (Or build it before as Brahma Dev suggests)

Answer (score 0):

I have understood the problem and founded the solution !!
A big thank to @Brahma Dev and @TGrif for their help !

The problem was that on the server I have node.js install globally (via apt-get) and an other version installed a the user which launch `npm run dev`

And if I execute `su myuser -c "node -v`, su doesn't execute .bashrc before `node -v`.
So if I execute `su myuser` and then `node -v`, the version of node is different !

I have solved the problem by creating an sh script containing :

  `export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
  [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
  [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
  npm run dev`

And now, `su myuser -c "./start-server.sh"` works !

So if I add `su myuser -c "/var/www/dialoguea.co.tools/dialoguea/start-server.sh" &` in /etc/rc.local the node.js server loads when ubuntu is restarted.