# Raspberry pi call workon cv in bash or python script

Tags: python, bash, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I try to run a python script at start of raspberry pi. In the python script I use `open cv` so I need to call before:

```
source ~/.profile
workon cv
```

I try to write a bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Bash script"
source ~/.profile
workon cv
#/usr/bin/python3 reco_eyes_from_video.py
python reco_eyes_from_video.py
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "reco_eyes_from_video.py", line 1, in <module>
import cv2
ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
```

If I call myself:

```
source ~/.profile
workon cv
```

and then:

```
python reco_eyes_from_video.py
```

it is working fine
There is any way to run `workon` at the start?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forget to write "python" before "reco_eyes_from_video.py" in your bash file.

To run this file at start, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12973826/7759641)

Comment: Yeah sorry, in my script i have it. All the time i get error. That error mean i don't have cv, and this is mean workon cv doesn't work

Comment: Did you check if you’re in the “cv” virtual environment after calling :
source ~/.profile
workon cv
a "cv" must appear in front of the prompt of your shell.
Check step 7 here: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/

Comment: If i call this via bash file I'm not in but if i call this one by one via terminal I am

Comment: I'm not expert on this question, but I know my bash scripts with Python call inside may work or not if I launch them with:
`bash myscript.sh`
or
`sh myscript.sh`
or
`./myscript.sh` (after making it executable via 'chmod +x myscript.sh)

Comment: Thx for help :). I reinstall python on rpi and tool python open cv and now it works.