# Other ways for auto-start script in Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, bash

So I'm basically wanting to get a script to run on system boot. It's basically an SSH callback. I've tried a few ways that I've gotten to work in the past on other distributions, but having a little bit of difficulty here.

First thing I've tried was adding the `/path/to/script.rb` to /etc/rc.local. However, this file does not exist on the latest version of Kali Linux. I tried to create it and replicate my old Ubuntu rc.local file, but it didn't run on system startup.

Next thing I tried was creating an executable bash script in /etc/init.d/, following the `update-rc.d script.sh defaults` and making the file executable. Restarted and nothing. If I run the script manually, it works. I tried to redirect the output to a file in the tmp folder, but it doesn't appear that there are any errors from what I'm understanding.

Are there any other ways to get an auto run script started other than these two methods? Seem to be the most common way to get this working, but it's just not doing it for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a shell script at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup)

Comment: Crontab did the trick for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Add script to

```
/etc/init.d
```

Run command:

```
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/script
```

Run command:

```
update-rc.d script enable
```

Comment: Default-start contains no runlevels, aborting. for me on kali 4.19.28-2 x86_64