# Trying ssh tunel at startup

Tags: shell, ssh, server, raspberry-pi, boot

I need that my server (raspberry/raspbian) execute a shell command at process startup (and not at login).

It is a command to let my server "ssh tunel" to a database :

```
ssh -fNg -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 <myuser>@<remoteIP> -p 22 -i <myprivatekey>
```

A website hosted on my server (HTTP/apache2) uses this tunel to log to its databse.

No one is logging in to the server, I saw rc.local as a solution but I think it only works by logging in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try solution with `crontab` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup)

```
#crontab -e
@reboot  /home/user/test.sh
```

Note, that if does not wotk from non-super-user set, try with sudo:

```
sudo crontab -e
@reboot  /home/user/test.sh
```

Of cause, put right command or script after `@reboot`