# Debian 9, delete file at startup

Tags: debian

Debian 9, default installation, nothing special, just pure and simple.

I want the file

```
/var/www/something/check.log
```

to be deleted every time the system boots.

How?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a shell script at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup)

Answer (score 0):

create a simple script `nano /home/user/boot.sh`
once inside add this code

```
#!/bin/bash
rm /var/www/something/check.log
```

Save the file.
give permissions to that file `chmod +x /home/user/boot.sh`

now open `crontab -e`
inside add the following line

```
@reboot /home/user/boot.sh
```

Save the cron, reboot and report feedback