# How to run test.sh instead of bash , when i ssh to debian jessie

Tags: bash, ssh, debian

I want to run test.sh instead of /bin/bash when i ssh to debian jessie.
is it possible ?how? 
thanks

Comment: Lots of ways to set that up, none of those ways on-topic here. Consider [unix.se] for questions that are about system configuration rather than software development.

Comment: [Put `ForceCommand` in a user-specific configuration file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464637/put-forcecommand-in-a-user-specific-configuration-file) is actually not far from what you need, even though the OP there is using it in a different context.

Comment: The example in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381930/ssh-and-sftp-setup-using-sshd-config also shows you how to intercept the user's requested command and substitute your own (whether conditionally or universally).

Comment: You can also set `test.sh` as your login shell.

Answer (score -1):

This question may be better suited for https://superuser.com. I'm not certain about what you're asking, but I have a few different interpretations. This question is somewhat vague, so I'll answer both what you actually said, and what I think you meant.

1. What it seems you actually asked is that you want to replace the Bash interpreter with your own code. My keyword for thinking this is "instead of." This is assuming that `test.sh` is a Bourne Shell-like interpreter, and that the shell you are currently running is NOT Bash. This can be achieved with the following (equivalent for the shell you are using):

   ```
   sudo cp ~/your_directory/test.sh /bin/
   sudo cp /bin/bash ~/your_directory/bash_backup
   sudo rm /bin/bash
   sudo mv /bin/test.sh /bin/bash
   ```

   This code will replace the file at `/bin/bash` with your `test.sh`. I don't recommend actually doing this, as you may not be able to recover the original functionality of Bash, depending on how your system is set up.
2. What I think you meant to ask would be how you can run `test.sh` at startup, then proceed normally. This has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/ddg#12973826

Comment: Replacing `/bin/bash` will not just change this one user account, but will also break every script with a `#!/bin/bash` shebang, probably including a large number of scripts provided by the pertinent OS vendor. The OP probably wants to have that one account use their script *instead of bash* as that account's effective "shell" (or, more precisely, its command run on login). The SSH `ForceCommand` mechanism is explicitly built for that purpose.

Comment: You're almost certainly right, but there wasn't enough information to tell for sure. I just tried to answer what OP asked.